# How to automatically script the securables assigned to a SQL account?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to generate a script to assign a user account to some securables, e.g. Table:Select.

How to do this?

Comment: you have the user assigned permissions to the securables already & you want to generate the grant statements?

Comment: yes, but automatically. Just like "Script>Create Table"

Comment: This has been answered in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and solved it with Justins suggestion.

- Right-click a template/example user in the database hive.
- Choose `properties`, `securables`.
- Make a change
- Do Ctrl+Shift+N to get a script of the change.

Comment: This work great for scripting new changes but not for scripting existing value. :(

Answer (score 1):

Link from RYU is dead.

Found another script that does the job here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/blogdoezequiel/archive/2010/04/26/the-sql-swiss-army-knife-1.aspx

In case it ever dies here it is:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[usp_SecurCreation]') AND OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsProcedure') = 1)
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SecurCreation]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_SecurCreation @User NVARCHAR(128) = NULL, @DB NVARCHAR(256) = NULL
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
-- 
--  Does not deal with CERTIFICATE_MAPPED_LOGIN and ASYMMETRIC_KEY_MAPPED_LOGIN types 
-- 
--  All users: EXEC usp_SecurCreation 
-- 
--  One user, All DBs: EXEC usp_SecurCreation '<User>'
--
--  One user, One DBs: EXEC usp_SecurCreation '<User>', '<DBName>'
--
--  All users, One DBs: EXEC usp_SecurCreation NULL, '<DBName>'
-- 

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @SC NVARCHAR(4000), @SCUser NVARCHAR(4000), @SCDB NVARCHAR(4000)
CREATE TABLE #TempSecurables ([State] VARCHAR(100),
            [State2] VARCHAR(100),
            [PermName] VARCHAR(100),
            [Type] NVARCHAR(60),
            [Grantor] VARCHAR(100),
            [User] VARCHAR(100)
            )    
CREATE TABLE #TempSecurables2 ([DBName] sysname,
                [State] VARCHAR(1000)
                )    

IF @User IS NULL AND @DB IS NULL
BEGIN
    --Server level Privileges to User or User Group

    INSERT INTO #TempSecurables
    SELECT CASE CAST(p.state AS VARCHAR(100)) WHEN 'D' THEN 'DENY' WHEN 'R' THEN 'REVOKE' WHEN 'G' THEN 'GRANT' WHEN 'W' THEN 'GRANT' END, 
    CASE CAST(p.state AS VARCHAR(100)) WHEN 'W' THEN 'WITH GRANT OPTION' ELSE '' END, CAST(p.permission_name AS VARCHAR(100)), RTRIM(p.class_desc),
    (SELECT [name] FROM sys.server_principals WHERE principal_id = p.grantor_principal_id), CAST(l.name AS VARCHAR(100))
    FROM sys.server_permissions p JOIN sys.server_principals l 
    ON p.grantee_principal_id = l.principal_id
    AND l.is_disabled = 0
    AND l.type IN ('S', 'U', 'G', 'R')

    INSERT INTO #TempSecurables2
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSforeachdb @command1='USE [?] 
    --Privileges for Procedures/Functions/CLR/Views to the User
    SELECT ''[?]'', CASE WHEN (b.state_desc COLLATE database_default) = ''GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'' THEN ''GRANT'' ELSE (b.state_desc COLLATE database_default) END + '' EXECUTE ON ['' + c.name + ''].['' + a.name + ''] TO '' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(b.grantee_principal_id)) +
    CASE STATE WHEN ''W'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM sys.all_objects a, sys.database_permissions b, sys.schemas c 
    WHERE a.OBJECT_ID = b.major_id AND a.type IN (''X'',''P'',''FN'',''AF'',''FS'',''FT'') AND b.grantee_principal_id <>0 
    AND b.grantee_principal_id <>2 AND a.schema_id = c.schema_id
    ORDER BY c.name

    --Table and View Level Privileges to the User
    SELECT ''[?]'', ''GRANT '' + privilege_type + '' ON ['' + table_schema + ''].['' + table_name + ''] TO ['' + grantee + '']'' +
    CASE IS_GRANTABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
    WHERE GRANTEE <> ''public''

    --Column Level Privileges to the User 
    SELECT ''[?]'', ''GRANT '' + privilege_type + '' ON ['' + table_schema + ''].['' + table_name + ''] ('' + column_name + '') TO ['' + grantee + '']'' +
    CASE IS_GRANTABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
    WHERE GRANTEE <> ''public'''
END
ELSE IF @User IS NULL AND @DB IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    --Server level Privileges to User or User Group

    INSERT INTO #TempSecurables
    SELECT CASE CAST(p.state AS VARCHAR(100)) WHEN 'D' THEN 'DENY' WHEN 'R' THEN 'REVOKE' WHEN 'G' THEN 'GRANT' WHEN 'W' THEN 'GRANT' END, 
    CASE CAST(p.state AS VARCHAR(100)) WHEN 'W' THEN 'WITH GRANT OPTION' ELSE '' END, CAST(p.permission_name AS VARCHAR(100)), RTRIM(p.class_desc),
    (SELECT [name] FROM sys.server_principals WHERE principal_id = p.grantor_principal_id), CAST(l.name AS VARCHAR(100))
    FROM sys.server_permissions AS p JOIN sys.server_principals AS l 
    ON p.grantee_principal_id = l.principal_id
    AND l.is_disabled = 0
    AND l.type IN ('S', 'U', 'G', 'R')

    SET @SCDB='USE [' + @DB + '] 
    --Privileges for Procedures/Functions/CLR/Views to the User
    SELECT ''[' + @DB + ']'', CASE WHEN (b.state_desc COLLATE database_default) = ''GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'' THEN ''GRANT'' ELSE (b.state_desc COLLATE database_default) END + '' EXECUTE ON ['' + c.name + ''].['' + a.name + ''] TO '' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(b.grantee_principal_id)) +
    CASE STATE WHEN ''W'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM sys.all_objects a, sys.database_permissions b, sys.schemas c 
    WHERE a.OBJECT_ID = b.major_id AND a.type IN (''X'',''P'',''FN'',''AF'',''FS'',''FT'') AND b.grantee_principal_id <>0 
    AND b.grantee_principal_id <>2 AND a.schema_id = c.schema_id
    ORDER BY c.name

    --Table and View Level Privileges to the User
    SELECT ''[' + @DB + ']'', ''GRANT '' + privilege_type + '' ON ['' + table_schema + ''].['' + table_name + ''] TO ['' + grantee + '']'' +
    CASE IS_GRANTABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
    WHERE GRANTEE <> ''public''

    --Column Level Privileges to the User 
    SELECT ''[' + @DB + ']'', ''GRANT '' + privilege_type + '' ON ['' + table_schema + ''].['' + table_name + ''] ('' + column_name + '') TO ['' + grantee + '']'' +
    CASE IS_GRANTABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
    WHERE GRANTEE <> ''public'''

    INSERT INTO #TempSecurables2
    EXEC master..sp_executesql @SCDB
END
ELSE IF @User IS NOT NULL AND @DB IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    --Server level Privileges to User or User Group

    INSERT INTO #TempSecurables
    SELECT CASE CAST(p.state AS VARCHAR(100)) WHEN 'D' THEN 'DENY' WHEN 'R' THEN 'REVOKE' WHEN 'G' THEN 'GRANT' WHEN 'W' THEN 'GRANT' END, 
    CASE CAST(p.state AS VARCHAR(100)) WHEN 'W' THEN 'WITH GRANT OPTION' ELSE '' END, CAST(p.permission_name AS VARCHAR(100)), RTRIM(p.class_desc),
    (SELECT [name] FROM sys.server_principals WHERE principal_id = p.grantor_principal_id), CAST(l.name AS VARCHAR(100))
    FROM sys.server_permissions AS p JOIN sys.server_principals AS l 
    ON p.grantee_principal_id = l.principal_id
    AND l.is_disabled = 0
    AND l.type IN ('S', 'U', 'G', 'R')
    AND QUOTENAME(l.name) = QUOTENAME(@User)

    SET @SCDB='USE [' + @DB + '] 
    --Privileges for Procedures/Functions/CLR/Views to the User
    SELECT ''[' + @DB + ']'', CASE WHEN (b.state_desc COLLATE database_default) = ''GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'' THEN ''GRANT'' ELSE (b.state_desc COLLATE database_default) END + '' EXECUTE ON ['' + c.name + ''].['' + a.name + ''] TO '' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(b.grantee_principal_id)) +
    CASE STATE WHEN ''W'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM sys.all_objects a, sys.database_permissions b, sys.schemas c 
    WHERE a.OBJECT_ID = b.major_id AND a.type IN (''X'',''P'',''FN'',''AF'',''FS'',''FT'') AND b.grantee_principal_id <>0 
    AND b.grantee_principal_id <>2 AND a.schema_id = c.schema_id
    AND QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(b.grantee_principal_id)) = ''[' + @User + ']''
    ORDER BY c.name

    --Table and View Level Privileges to the User
    SELECT ''[' + @DB + ']'', ''GRANT '' + privilege_type + '' ON ['' + table_schema + ''].['' + table_name + ''] TO ['' + grantee + '']'' +
    CASE IS_GRANTABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
    WHERE GRANTEE <> ''public''
    AND grantee = ''[' + @User + ']''

    --Column Level Privileges to the User 
    SELECT ''[' + @DB + ']'', ''GRANT '' + privilege_type + '' ON ['' + table_schema + ''].['' + table_name + ''] ('' + column_name + '') TO ['' + grantee + '']'' +
    CASE IS_GRANTABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
    WHERE GRANTEE <> ''public''
    AND grantee = ''[' + @User + ']'''

    INSERT INTO #TempSecurables2
    EXEC master..sp_executesql @SCDB
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    --Server level Privileges to User or User Group
    INSERT INTO #TempSecurables
    SELECT CASE CAST(p.state AS VARCHAR(100)) WHEN 'D' THEN 'DENY' WHEN 'R' THEN 'REVOKE' WHEN 'G' THEN 'GRANT' WHEN 'W' THEN 'GRANT' END, 
    CASE CAST(p.state AS VARCHAR(100)) WHEN 'W' THEN 'WITH GRANT OPTION' ELSE '' END, CAST(p.permission_name AS VARCHAR(100)), RTRIM(p.class_desc),
    (SELECT [name] FROM sys.server_principals WHERE principal_id = p.grantor_principal_id), CAST(l.name AS VARCHAR(100))
    FROM sys.server_permissions p JOIN sys.server_principals l 
    ON p.grantee_principal_id = l.principal_id
    AND l.is_disabled = 0
    AND l.type IN ('S', 'U', 'G', 'R')
    AND QUOTENAME(l.name) = QUOTENAME(@User)

    SET @SCUser = 'USE [?] 
    --Privileges for Procedures/Functions/CLR/Views to the User
    SELECT ''[?]'', CASE WHEN (b.state_desc COLLATE database_default) = ''GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTION'' THEN ''GRANT'' ELSE (b.state_desc COLLATE database_default) END + '' EXECUTE ON ['' + c.name + ''].['' + a.name + ''] TO '' + QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(b.grantee_principal_id)) +
    CASE STATE WHEN ''W'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM sys.all_objects a, sys.database_permissions b, sys.schemas c 
    WHERE a.OBJECT_ID = b.major_id AND a.type IN (''X'',''P'',''FN'',''AF'',''FS'',''FT'') AND b.grantee_principal_id <>0 
    AND b.grantee_principal_id <>2 AND a.schema_id = c.schema_id
    AND QUOTENAME(USER_NAME(b.grantee_principal_id)) = ''[' + @User + ']''
    ORDER BY c.name

    --Table and View Level Privileges to the User
    SELECT ''[?]'', ''GRANT '' + privilege_type + '' ON ['' + table_schema + ''].['' + table_name + ''] TO ['' + grantee + '']'' +
    CASE IS_GRANTABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
    WHERE GRANTEE <> ''public''
    AND grantee = ''[' + @User + ']''

    --Column Level Privileges to the User 
    SELECT ''[?]'', ''GRANT '' + privilege_type + '' ON ['' + table_schema + ''].['' + table_name + ''] ('' + column_name + '') TO ['' + grantee + '']'' +
    CASE IS_GRANTABLE WHEN ''YES'' THEN '' WITH GRANT OPTION'' 
    ELSE '''' END FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN_PRIVILEGES
    WHERE GRANTEE <> ''public''
    AND grantee = ''[' + @User + ']'''

    INSERT INTO #TempSecurables2
    EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSforeachdb @command1=@SCUser
END

DECLARE @tmpstr NVARCHAR(128)
SET @tmpstr = '** Generated ' + CONVERT (VARCHAR, GETDATE()) + ' on ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' */'
PRINT @tmpstr

PRINT CHAR(13) + '--##### Server level Privileges to User or User Group #####' + CHAR(13)

DECLARE cSC CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT 'USE [master];' + CHAR(10) + RTRIM(ts.[State]) + ' ' + RTRIM(ts.[PermName]) + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(RTRIM(ts.[User])) + ' ' + RTRIM(ts.[State2]) + ';' + CHAR(10) + 'GO' FROM #TempSecurables ts WHERE RTRIM([Type]) = 'SERVER'
OPEN cSC  
FETCH NEXT FROM cSC INTO @SC
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        PRINT @SC
        FETCH NEXT FROM cSC INTO @SC
    END
CLOSE cSC 
DEALLOCATE cSC

DECLARE cSC CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT 'USE [master];' + CHAR(10) + RTRIM(ts.[State]) + ' ' + RTRIM(ts.[PermName]) + ' ON ' + CASE WHEN RTRIM(ts.[Type]) = 'SERVER_PRINCIPAL' THEN 'LOGIN' ELSE 'ENDPOINT' END + '::' + QUOTENAME(RTRIM(ts.[Grantor])) + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(RTRIM(ts.[User])) + ' ' +RTRIM(ts.[State2]) + ';' + CHAR(10) + 'GO' FROM #TempSecurables ts WHERE RTRIM([Type]) <> 'SERVER'
OPEN cSC  
FETCH NEXT FROM cSC INTO @SC
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        PRINT @SC
        FETCH NEXT FROM cSC INTO @SC
    END
CLOSE cSC 
DEALLOCATE cSC
DROP TABLE #TempSecurables

PRINT CHAR(13) + '--##### Procedures/Functions/CLR/Views, Table and Column Level Privileges to the User #####' + CHAR(13)

DECLARE cSC CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT 'USE ' + ts2.DBName +';' + CHAR(10) + RTRIM(ts2.[State]) + ';' + CHAR(10) + 'GO' FROM #TempSecurables2 ts2
OPEN cSC  
FETCH NEXT FROM cSC INTO @SC
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        PRINT @SC
        FETCH NEXT FROM cSC INTO @SC
    END
CLOSE cSC 
DEALLOCATE cSC

DROP TABLE #TempSecurables2
GO
```

Comment: This script does not handle database roles memberships

Answer (score 1):

Back then I've created this small script to query permissions in our server. It was the first time I could make use of SQL cursors.. :) Hope this helps:

```
 --cursor
drop table #permission_report
--create #temp table
CREATE TABLE #permission_report
   (db_name varchar(50),
  username varchar(50),
  objectname varchar(100),
  objectclass varchar(50),
  permission_name varchar(50),
  state varchar(50))
```

declare @dbname VARCHAR(50)

--declare cursor in order to run on every database on the server
DECLARE  c_dbnames CURSOR FOR
SELECT name 
FROM sys.databases

OPEN c_dbnames

FETCH c_dbnames INTO @dbname
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
--Openrowset to select the appropriate columns from system catalog views
--insert result into #temp table
--repeat task on every database on server
  EXEC('INSERT INTO #permission_report(db_name,username,objectname,objectclass,permission_name,state)

`SELECT '''+@dbname+''',p.name username, o.name objectname, class_desc,permission_name, state_desc
FROM ' + @dbname +'.sys.database_principals p
JOIN ' + @dbname +'.sys.database_permissions d ON d.grantee_principal_id = p.principal_id
JOIN ' + @dbname +'.sys.objects o ON o.object_id = d.major_id where p.name=''Yourdomain\User''') ---checking only EMRSN\USMTN-FF20_Users

  FETCH c_dbnames INTO @dbname
END

CLOSE c_dbnames
DEALLOCATE c_dbnames

SELECT * FROM #permission_report`

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the where clause of the object selection as you see fit.  Should be minimal tweeking if you are looking for a 2005 or 2008 script.

/*Caution!*/ This script can be a little dangerous.

```
Declare @TableName varchar(100),
   @Sql nvarchar(500),
   @Result int,
   @UserName nvarchar(258)
   set @UserName= QuoteName('<your_user>')
Print @UserName

  DECLARE
     Your_Cursor cursor
     LOCAL
     FORWARD_ONLY
     OPTIMISTIC
  FOR  
/* if you only want one object to apply permissions to*/
-- select Name from Sysobjects where name = 'Your_TableName'
/*tables*/-- select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'U' order by name
/*views*/-- select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'V' order by name
/*StoredPs*/-- select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'P' order by name
/*UDFs*/-- select name from sysobjects where xtype = 'FN' order by name
/**********************************************************************/


OPEN Your_Cursor
FETCH NEXT from Your_Cursor into @TableName
while (@@fetch_status = 0)
   begin
/*Tables*/
--      set @Sql = N'Grant Select On '+ @TableName+ N' To ' + @UserName
--      set exec @Result = sp_executeSql @Sql
--      if @Result = 0
--        begin
--          Print 'Granted Select On '+ @TableName + ' by ' + @UserName
--        end
--      set @Sql = N'Grant Insert On '+ @TableName+ N' To ' + @UserName
--      set exec @Result = sp_executeSql @Sql
--      if @Result = 0
--        begin
--          Print 'Granted Insert On '+ @TableName + ' by ' + @UserName
--        end
--      set @Sql = N'Grant Update On '+ @TableName+ N' To '+ @UserName
--      set exec @Result = sp_executeSql @Sql
--      if @Result = 0
--        begin
--          Print 'Granted Update On '+ @TableName + ' by ' + @UserName
--        end
--      set @Sql = N'Grant Delete On '+ @TableName+ N' To '+ @UserName
--      set exec @Result = sp_executeSql @Sql
--      if @Result = 0
--        begin
--          Print 'Granted Delete On '+ @TableName + ' by ' + @UserName
--        end
/*Stored Procs and UDFs*/
--      set @Sql = N'Grant Execute On '+ @TableName+ N' To '+ @UserName
--      set exec @Result = sp_executeSql @Sql
--      if @Result = 0
--        begin
--          Print 'Granted Execute On '+ @TableName + ' by ' + @UserName
--        end
     FETCH NEXT from your_Cursor into @TableName
   end
CLOSE Your_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Your_Cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated script I found here https://www.databasejournal.com/ms-sql/re-generating-sql-server-logins-part-2/ for newer version of MS SQL server - it generates following for example:

> -- Create database user for login
>
> USE [master]
>
> IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name =
> 'YourLoginName')
>
> BEGIN
> CREATE USER [YourLoginName] FOR LOGIN [YourLoginName] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo] END GO
>
> --Grant all securable class to login
>
> USE [master] GRANT CONNECT TO [YourLoginName] GO

```
----------------

--Login Pre-requisites

----------------

set concat_null_yields_null off

USE master
go

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @login_name varchar(100)

SET @login_name = 'YourSQLloginName'
---------------------–
IF lower(@login_name) IN ('sa','public')

BEGIN
          RAISERROR (15405,11,1,@login_name)
          RETURN
END

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals WHERE name = @login_name AND type IN ('G','U','S'))

BEGIN
          PRINT 'Please input valid login name'
          RETURN
END

DECLARE @login_sid varbinary(85)

SELECT @login_sid = sid FROM sys.server_principals 
WHERE name = @login_name

DECLARE @maxid int

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#db_users') is not null

BEGIN
          DROP TABLE #db_users
END

SELECT id = identity(int,1,1), sql_cmd = 'SELECT '''+name+''', * FROM ['+name+'].sys.database_principals' INTO #db_users FROM sys.databases
WHERE state_desc <> 'OFFLINE'

SELECT @maxid = @@ROWCOUNT
----------------
--–Create Server Role Temp table
----------------

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#srvrole') IS NOT NULL

BEGIN
          DROP TABLE #srvrole
END

CREATE TABLE #srvrole(ServerRole sysname, MemberName sysname, MemberSID varbinary(85)) 

INSERT INTO [#srvrole] EXEC sp_helpsrvrolemember
DECLARE @login_srvrole varchar(1000)

SET @login_srvrole = ''

IF EXISTS (select * from [#srvrole] where ServerRole = 'sysadmin' AND MemberName = @login_name)

BEGIN
          PRINT '–Login ['+@login_name+'] is part of sysadmin server role, hence possesses full
privileges for SQL instance: '+@@servername

          PRINT 'GO'

          SELECT @login_srvrole =
@login_srvrole + 'EXEC
sp_addsrvrolemember '''+MemberName+''','''+ServerRole+''''+CHAR(10) FROM #srvrole

          WHERE [MemberName] = @login_name
          PRINT @login_srvrole
          RETURN
          RETURN
END
-----------------

--Find out list of db that the
--login has access to

-----------------
PRINT ''
PRINT '----------------'
PRINT '–Create database user for login '
PRINT '----------------'

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#alldb_users') is not null

BEGIN
          DROP TABLE #alldb_users
END

CREATE TABLE #alldb_users(

          [dbname][sysname] NOT NULL,
          [name][sysname] NOT NULL,
          [principal_id][int] NOT NULL,
          [type][char](1) NOT NULL,
          [type_desc][nvarchar](60) NULL,
          [default_schema_name][sysname] NULL,
          [create_date][datetime] NOT NULL,
          [modify_date][datetime] NOT NULL,
          [owning_principal_id][int] NULL,
          [sid][varbinary](85)NULL,
          [is_fixed_role][bit] NOT NULL,
          [authentication_type][int] NOT NULL,
          [authentication_type_desc][nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
          [default_language_name][sysname] NULL,
          [default_language_lcid][int] NULL,
          [allow_encrypted_value_modifications][bit] NOT NULL
) 

DECLARE @id int, @sqlcmd varchar(500)
SET @id = 1

WHILE @id <=@maxid
BEGIN
          SELECT @sqlcmd = sql_cmd FROM #db_users WHERE id = @id
          INSERT INTO #alldb_users EXEC (@sqlcmd)
          SET @id = @id + 1
END

DELETE FROM #alldb_users WHERE sid is null
DELETE FROM #alldb_users WHERE sid <> @login_sid

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #alldb_users )
BEGIN
          PRINT '–Login ['+@login_name+'] doesnt have access to any database'
END

DECLARE @name sysname, @dbname sysname, @schema sysname, @dbuser_cmd varchar(8000)
DECLARE dbuser_cursor CURSOR
FAST_FORWARD FOR

SELECT dbname, name, default_schema_name
FROM #alldb_users
OPEN dbuser_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dbuser_cursor INTO @dbname, @name, @schema

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
IF @schema IS NOT NULL

BEGIN    
SELECT @dbuser_cmd = 'USE ['+dbname+']

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
sys.database_principals WHERE name = '''+name+''')

BEGIN
          CREATE
USER ['+@name+'] FOR LOGIN ['+@login_name+']'+isnull(' WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=['+default_schema_name+']','')+'
END
GO

' FROM #alldb_users WHERE name = @name and dbname = @dbname
END

ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT @dbuser_cmd = 'USE ['+dbname+']

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM
sys.database_principals WHERE name = '''+name+''')
BEGIN
          CREATE
USER ['+@name+'] FOR LOGIN ['+@login_name+']
END
GO
' FROM #alldb_users WHERE name = @name and dbname = @dbname
END
          print @dbuser_cmd

    FETCH NEXT FROM dbuser_cursor INTO
@dbname, @name,
@schema
    END
CLOSE dbuser_cursor
DEALLOCATE dbuser_cursor
----------------

--Create DB Role Temp table

----------------
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dbrole') is not null

BEGIN
          DROP TABLE #dbrole
END

create table #dbrole (id int identity(1,1), dbname varchar(100), dbrole varchar (100), dbrole_member varchar(100), sid varbinary(85),
default_schema_name varchar(100), login_name varchar(100), db_principal_id int)

DECLARE @dbrole_sqlcmd varchar(max)
DECLARE dbrole_cursor CURSOR
FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT
'SELECT '''+dbname+''', c.name, b.name, b.sid, b.default_schema_name, d.name,
b.principal_id as login_name
from ['+dbname+'].sys.database_role_members a
inner join ['+dbname+'].sys.database_principals b on a.member_principal_id = b.principal_id
inner join ['+dbname+'].sys.database_principals c on a.role_principal_id = c.principal_id
left join sys.server_principals d on b.sid = d.sid
where d.name= '''+@login_name+''''
from #alldb_users
OPEN dbrole_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dbrole_cursor INTO @dbrole_sqlcmd
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #dbrole (dbname, dbrole,
dbrole_member, sid, default_schema_name,
login_name, db_principal_id) exec(@dbrole_sqlcmd)
    FETCH NEXT FROM dbrole_cursor INTO @dbrole_sqlcmd
    END
CLOSE dbrole_cursor

DEALLOCATE dbrole_cursor
DELETE FROM #dbrole WHERE sid <> @login_sid

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #dbrole where
dbrole = 'db_owner')
BEGIN
          PRINT '----------------'
          PRINT'–Login is db_owner of below databases'
          PRINT'----------------'
END

DECLARE @dbname_dbowner varchar(100), @dbrole_member varchar(100)
DECLARE dbowner_cursor CURSOR
FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT dbname, dbrole_member from #dbrole where
dbrole = 'db_owner'
OPEN dbowner_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dbowner_cursor INTO
@dbname_dbowner, @dbrole_member
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
          PRINT 'USE ['+@dbname_dbowner+']
EXEC sp_addrolemember ''db_owner'','''+@dbrole_member +'''
GO'
    FETCH NEXT FROM dbowner_cursor INTO @dbname_dbowner, @dbrole_member
    END
CLOSE dbowner_cursor

DEALLOCATE dbowner_cursor
----------------------------------–
--–-Find out what database the login
--has permission to access (avoid restricted and single user database)
----------------------------------–
DELETE From #srvrole where MemberName <>
@login_name
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#alldb_users_access') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
          DROP TABLE #alldb_users_access
END
SELECT a.*, collation_name INTO #alldb_users_access FROM
#alldb_users a inner join
sys.databases b ON a.dbname = b.name
WHERE user_access = 0
OR
(user_access = 2 and exists (SELECT * FROM #srvrole WHERE
ServerRole in ('dbcreator','sysadmin')))
OR
(user_access = 2 and a.dbname in (SELECT dbname FROM #dbrole WHERE dbrole = 'db_owner'
AND login_name = @login_name))
----------------------------------–
--Remove database that login doesnt
--have permission to connect
----------------------------------–
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dbconnect') is not null
BEGIN
          DROP TABLE #dbconnect
END

CREATE TABLE #dbconnect ( dbname varchar(100), connect_status bit)
DECLARE @dbconnect_sqlcmd varchar(1000)
SET @dbconnect_sqlcmd  = ''

DECLARE dbbconnect_cursor CURSOR
FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT 'select distinct '''+dbname+''', 1 from ['+dbname+'].sys.database_permissions a
inner join ['+dbname+'].sys.database_principals b on a.grantee_principal_id = b.principal_id
inner join ['+dbname+'].sys.server_principals c on b.sid = c.sid
where c.name = '''+@login_name+''''
from #alldb_users_access
OPEN dbbconnect_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dbbconnect_cursor INTO @dbconnect_sqlcmd
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
          INSERT INTO #dbconnect exec(@dbconnect_sqlcmd)
    FETCH NEXT FROM dbbconnect_cursor INTO @dbconnect_sqlcmd
    END
CLOSE dbbconnect_cursor
DEALLOCATE dbbconnect_cursor

insert into #dbconnect

select a.dbname, 0 from #alldb_users_access a
left join #dbconnect b on a.dbname = b.dbname
where b.dbname is null
-----------------------------
--Grant
--all securable class to login
------------------------------

PRINT ''
PRINT '----------------'
PRINT '–Grant all securable class to login '
PRINT '----------------'
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#securable_class') is not null

BEGIN
          DROP TABLE #securable_class
END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dblevel') is not null
BEGIN
          DROP TABLE #dblevel
END

create table #dblevel (login_name varchar(256), dbname sysname, dbuser_name varchar(100), class_desc varchar(100), permission_name varchar(100), state_desc varchar(100))

DECLARE @dblevel_sqlcmd varchar(1000)

DECLARE dblevel_cursor CURSOR
FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT 'select '''+@login_name+''' as login_name, '''+dbname+''' as dbname, b.name as dbuser_name, a.class_desc, a.permission_name, state_desc
 from ['+dbname+'].sys.database_permissions a 
 inner join ['+dbname+'].sys.database_principals b
on a.grantee_principal_id = b.principal_id
where b.name in (''public'','''+name+''')
and class_desc = ''DATABASE'''
FROM #alldb_users_access

union

SELECT 'select '''+@login_name+''' as login_name, ''master'' as dbname, b.name as dbuser_name, a.class_desc, a.permission_name, state_desc 
from sys.server_permissions a 
inner join sys.server_principals b on a.grantee_principal_id = b.principal_id
where b.name = '''+@login_name+''''

UNION

SELECT 'select '''+@login_name+''' as login_name, ''master'' as dbname, b.name as dbuser_name, a.class_desc, a.permission_name, state_desc 
from sys.server_permissions a 
inner join sys.server_principals b on a.grantee_principal_id = b.principal_id and class_desc = ''SERVER''
where b.name = ''public''' 

OPEN dblevel_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM dblevel_cursor INTO
@dblevel_sqlcmd
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #dblevel (login_name, dbname, dbuser_name, class_desc, permission_name, state_desc) 
EXEC (@dblevel_sqlcmd)
    FETCH NEXT FROM dblevel_cursor INTO @dblevel_sqlcmd
    END
CLOSE dblevel_cursor
DEALLOCATE dblevel_cursor

SET NOCOUNT ON
DELETE FROM #dblevel WHERE permission_name IN ('SELECT','INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','REFERENCES')

DELETE FROM #dblevel WHERE dbname IN (SELECT dbname FROM #dbrole 
WHERE sid = @login_sid AND dbrole = 'db_owner')

DECLARE @securable_sqlcmd varchar(150)
DECLARE securable_cursor CURSOR
FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT distinct 'USE ['+dbname+']
GRANT '+permission_name+' TO ['+@login_name+']
GO
' FROM #dblevel
OPEN securable_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM securable_cursor INTO @securable_sqlcmd
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
          PRINT @securable_sqlcmd
          FETCH NEXT FROM securable_cursor INTO @securable_sqlcmd
END

CLOSE securable_cursor
DEALLOCATE securable_cursor
```