# SQL Server query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, permissions, user-permissions

I would like to write a query on a sql 2008 that will report all the users that have access to a specific database, or objects within the database such as tables, views, and stored procedures, either directly or due to roles, etc.  This report would be used for security auditing purposes.  Not sure if anyone has a query that will fit my needs completely, but hopefully something that will give me a good start. Either sql 2008, 2005 or 2000 will do, I can probably convert as needed.

Comment: I wish I had a query like this - I'd love to see a list of who has access to an object, so I'm hoping you get an answer!

Comment: Not sure if Jeremy wanted roles expanded or not, but I do. :)

Answer (score 372, accepted):

This is my first crack at a query, based on [Andomar's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049010/1501497) suggestions.  This query is intended to provide a list of permissions that a user has either applied directly to the user account, or through
roles that the user has.

```
/*
Security Audit Report
1) List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group directly 
2) List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
3) List all access provisioned to the public role

Columns Returned:
UserName        : SQL or Windows/Active Directory user account.  This could also be an Active Directory group.
UserType        : Value will be either 'SQL User' or 'Windows User'.  This reflects the type of user defined for the 
                  SQL Server user account.
DatabaseUserName: Name of the associated user as defined in the database user account.  The database user may not be the
                  same as the server user.
Role            : The role name.  This will be null if the associated permissions to the object are defined at directly
                  on the user account, otherwise this will be the name of the role that the user is a member of.
PermissionType  : Type of permissions the user/role has on an object. Examples could include CONNECT, EXECUTE, SELECT
                  DELETE, INSERT, ALTER, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP, VIEW DEFINITION, etc.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
PermissionState : Reflects the state of the permission type, examples could include GRANT, DENY, etc.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
ObjectType      : Type of object the user/role is assigned permissions on.  Examples could include USER_TABLE, 
                  SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION, SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION, SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE, VIEW, etc.   
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.          
ObjectName      : Name of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on.  
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
ColumnName      : Name of the column of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on. This value
                  is only populated if the object is a table, view or a table value function.                 
*/

--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group directly 
SELECT  
    [UserName] = CASE princ.[type] 
                    WHEN 'S' THEN princ.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                 END,  
    [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],       
    [Role] = null,      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],       
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --database user
    sys.database_principals princ  
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE 
    princ.[type] in ('S','U')
UNION
--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
SELECT  
    [UserName] = CASE memberprinc.[type] 
                    WHEN 'S' THEN memberprinc.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                 END, 
    [DatabaseUserName] = memberprinc.[name],   
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],   
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --Role/member associations
    sys.database_role_members members
JOIN
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
JOIN
    --Role members (database users)
    sys.database_principals memberprinc ON memberprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on memberprinc.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
UNION
--List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
SELECT  
    [UserName] = '{All Users}',
    [UserType] = '{All Users}', 
    [DatabaseUserName] = '{All Users}',       
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],  
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc
LEFT JOIN        
    --Role permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]                   
JOIN 
    --All objects   
    sys.objects obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE
    --Only roles
    roleprinc.[type] = 'R' AND
    --Only public role
    roleprinc.[name] = 'public' AND
    --Only objects of ours, not the MS objects
    obj.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY
    princ.[Name],
    OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    col.[name],
    perm.[permission_name],
    perm.[state_desc],
    obj.type_desc--perm.[class_desc]
```

Comment: This is just what my business user wants to see, as it expands the roles out, so you can see all individual objects that each user has access to.  Takes ages to run but who cares.

Comment: This is an awesome script, but I had to adjust it some to account for schemas better.  When perm.class_desc was set to SCHEMA it was mistakenly saying it had the schema granted access to some system table.

I ended up adding a LEFT JOIN to sys.schemas ON perm.major_id = schem.schema_id and changing two select statements:


    [ObjectType] = CASE WHEN perm.class_desc <> 'SCHEMA' THEN obj.type_desc ELSE 'SCHEMA' END,
    [ObjectName] = CASE WHEN perm.class_desc <> 'SCHEMA' THEN OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id) ELSE schem.name END,

Probably not the best way to do it, but the only quick way I found.

Comment: I'd like to add how long it took my server to process this. I have a very decent server and this script took 5:45 to run. That's 5 hours and 45 mins for ~60 databases and ~100 user accounts.

Comment: For an impersonate, this script returns 1st three columns followed by all nulls for the <user> in "grant impersonate on <user> from <fromUserOrRole>".  Was trying to drop user and it was hard to figure out that last permission.

Comment: Looking at edit history, **Sean Rose's answer** appears to be the most comprehensive in terms of incorporating the other suggestions made on this page

Comment: This does not return permissions assigned directly to windows users on my database, although @Andromar's report does.  Not sure what the issue is.

Comment: in Azure SQL DB `login_token` changed to `user_token`

Comment: Just wondering, why do you need COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI?  I'm updating my answer below to exclude it as I don't think it's necessary?

Comment: Also, see my answer below, which was based off your answer.  It appears using sys.login_token is not very robust, and should use sys.server_principals instead. as recommended by iw.kuchin and incorporated by @SeanRose in his answer.

Comment: This script does not show permissions granted through database roles. The user has `SHOWPLAN` permission on the database level (`SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'DATABASE') WHERE Permission_Name = 'SHOWPLAN'; `), but that permission does not appear anywhere in the results of this query.

Answer (score 132):

Here is a complete version of [Jeremy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059579/1501497) Aug 2011 query with the changes suggested by Brad (Oct 2011) and [iw.kuchin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10715731/1501497) (May 2012) incorporated:

1. *Brad:*  Correct `[ObjectType]` and `[ObjectName]` for schemas.
2. *iw.kuchin:*  For `[ObjectType]` it's better to use `obj.type_desc` only for `OBJECT_OR_COLUMN` permission class. For all other cases use `perm.[class_desc]`.
3. *iw.kuchin:*  Handle `IMPERSONATE` permissions.
4. *iw.kuchin:*  Replace `sys.login_token` with `sys.server_principals` as it will show also SQL Logins, not only Windows ones.
5. *iw.kuchin:*  Include Windows groups.
6. *iw.kuchin:*  Exclude users `sys` and INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Hopefully this saves someone else an hour or two of their lives. `:)`

```
/*
Security Audit Report
1) List all access provisioned to a SQL user or Windows user/group directly
2) List all access provisioned to a SQL user or Windows user/group through a database or application role
3) List all access provisioned to the public role

Columns Returned:
UserType        : Value will be either 'SQL User', 'Windows User', or 'Windows Group'.
                  This reflects the type of user/group defined for the SQL Server account.
DatabaseUserName: Name of the associated user as defined in the database user account.  The database user may not be the
                  same as the server user.
LoginName       : SQL or Windows/Active Directory user account.  This could also be an Active Directory group.
Role            : The role name.  This will be null if the associated permissions to the object are defined at directly
                  on the user account, otherwise this will be the name of the role that the user is a member of.
PermissionType  : Type of permissions the user/role has on an object. Examples could include CONNECT, EXECUTE, SELECT
                  DELETE, INSERT, ALTER, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP, VIEW DEFINITION, etc.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
PermissionState : Reflects the state of the permission type, examples could include GRANT, DENY, etc.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
ObjectType      : Type of object the user/role is assigned permissions on.  Examples could include USER_TABLE,
                  SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION, SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION, SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE, VIEW, etc.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
Schema          : Name of the schema the object is in.
ObjectName      : Name of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
ColumnName      : Name of the column of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on. This value
                  is only populated if the object is a table, view or a table value function.
*/

    --1) List all access provisioned to a SQL user or Windows user/group directly
    SELECT
        [UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                         WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                         WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                         WHEN 'G' THEN 'Windows Group'
                     END,
        [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],
        [LoginName]        = ulogin.[name],
        [Role]             = NULL,
        [PermissionType]   = perm.[permission_name],
        [PermissionState]  = perm.[state_desc],
        [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc]        -- Schema-contained objects
                           ELSE perm.[class_desc]             -- Higher-level objects
                       END,
        [Schema] = objschem.[name],
        [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name]       -- Schemas
                           WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]             -- Impersonations
                           ELSE OBJECT_NAME(perm.[major_id])  -- General objects
                       END,
        [ColumnName] = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Database user
        sys.database_principals            AS princ
        --Login accounts
        LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals    AS ulogin    ON ulogin.[sid] = princ.[sid]
        --Permissions
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions AS perm      ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.objects              AS obj       ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS objschem  ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
        --Table columns
        LEFT JOIN sys.columns              AS col       ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                           AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
        --Impersonations
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals  AS imp       ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE
        princ.[type] IN ('S','U','G')
        -- No need for these system accounts
        AND princ.[name] NOT IN ('sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')

UNION

    --2) List all access provisioned to a SQL user or Windows user/group through a database or application role
    SELECT
        [UserType] = CASE membprinc.[type]
                         WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                         WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                         WHEN 'G' THEN 'Windows Group'
                     END,
        [DatabaseUserName] = membprinc.[name],
        [LoginName]        = ulogin.[name],
        [Role]             = roleprinc.[name],
        [PermissionType]   = perm.[permission_name],
        [PermissionState]  = perm.[state_desc],
        [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc]        -- Schema-contained objects
                           ELSE perm.[class_desc]             -- Higher-level objects
                       END,
        [Schema] = objschem.[name],
        [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name]       -- Schemas
                           WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]             -- Impersonations
                           ELSE OBJECT_NAME(perm.[major_id])  -- General objects
                       END,
        [ColumnName] = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Role/member associations
        sys.database_role_members          AS members
        --Roles
        JOIN      sys.database_principals  AS roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
        --Role members (database users)
        JOIN      sys.database_principals  AS membprinc ON membprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
        --Login accounts
        LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals    AS ulogin    ON ulogin.[sid] = membprinc.[sid]
        --Permissions
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions AS perm      ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.objects              AS obj       ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS objschem  ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
        --Table columns
        LEFT JOIN sys.columns              AS col       ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                           AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
        --Impersonations
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals  AS imp       ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE
        membprinc.[type] IN ('S','U','G')
        -- No need for these system accounts
        AND membprinc.[name] NOT IN ('sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')

UNION

    --3) List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
    SELECT
        [UserType]         = '{All Users}',
        [DatabaseUserName] = '{All Users}',
        [LoginName]        = '{All Users}',
        [Role]             = roleprinc.[name],
        [PermissionType]   = perm.[permission_name],
        [PermissionState]  = perm.[state_desc],
        [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc]        -- Schema-contained objects
                           ELSE perm.[class_desc]             -- Higher-level objects
                       END,
        [Schema] = objschem.[name],
        [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name]       -- Schemas
                           WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]             -- Impersonations
                           ELSE OBJECT_NAME(perm.[major_id])  -- General objects
                       END,
        [ColumnName] = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Roles
        sys.database_principals            AS roleprinc
        --Role permissions
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions AS perm      ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
        --All objects
        JOIN      sys.objects              AS obj       ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS objschem  ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
        --Table columns
        LEFT JOIN sys.columns              AS col       ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                           AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
        --Impersonations
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals  AS imp       ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE
        roleprinc.[type] = 'R'
        AND roleprinc.[name] = 'public'
        AND obj.[is_ms_shipped] = 0

ORDER BY
    [UserType],
    [DatabaseUserName],
    [LoginName],
    [Role],
    [Schema],
    [ObjectName],
    [ColumnName],
    [PermissionType],
    [PermissionState],
    [ObjectType]
```

Comment: Would be nice if it could do this for all db on the server

Comment: It doesn't seem to include the other users who are not the one connected, and who are sysadmins.

Comment: As @JakubP commented above, if you're using Azure SQL, neither `sys.login_token` nor `sys.server_principals` is supported and need to be replaced with `sys.user_token`

Comment: Thanks for this. If you use Azure SQL and Azure AD security groups, on query 1 and 2 you can change your `WHERE membprinc/princ.[type] in ...` condition to `WHERE membprinc/princ.[type] IN ('S','U','G', 'E', 'X')` and add the following conditions to the `CASE` on top: `WHEN 'E' THEN 'External user AAD'`and `WHEN 'X' THEN 'External group AAD'`. This way, Azure AD users and groups are also included. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @Rui Lopes, I tried your suggestion by updating the 2nd query with the changes you mentioned but it still gave the same output and didn't displayed the AD groups I have in Azure DWH.

Answer (score 91):

From SQL Server 2005 on, you can use system views for that.  For example, this query lists all users in a database, with their rights:

```
select  princ.name
,       princ.type_desc
,       perm.permission_name
,       perm.state_desc
,       perm.class_desc
,       object_name(perm.major_id)
from    sys.database_principals princ
left join
        sys.database_permissions perm
on      perm.grantee_principal_id = princ.principal_id
```

Be aware that a user can have rights through a role as well.  For example, the `db_data_reader` role grants `select` rights on most objects.

Comment: This runs heaps faster, but you have to do a second lookup (against the role) to see what objects a user can see via their roles.

Comment: For *Azure SQL*, I found this solution more robust than the accepted answer. Importantly, this recognizes external (Azure Active Directory) principals in database (`select * from sys.database_principals where type_desc = 'EXTERNAL_GROUP'`), whereas accepted answer does not, even after fixing `sys.user_token`.

Comment: Allowing for other class_desc:
`SELECT PrincipalName = p.[name],
p.[type_desc],
dp.[permission_name],
dp.[state_desc],
CASE dp.class_desc
WHEN 'DATABASE' THEN DB_NAME(dp.major_id)
WHEN 'SCHEMA' THEN SCHEMA_NAME(dp.major_id)
WHEN 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' THEN CONCAT_WS('.', OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(dp.major_id), OBJECT_NAME(dp.major_id), c.[name])
END
FROM sys.database_principals AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_permissions AS dp
ON p.principal_id = dp.grantee_principal_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.columns AS c
ON dp.major_id = c.[object_id]
AND dp.minor_id = c.column_id`

Answer (score 34):

Can't comment on accepted answer so I'll add some comments here:

- I second Brad on schemas issue. From MS reference `sys.objects` table contains only schema-scoped objects. So to get info about "higher level" objects (i.e. schemas in our case) you need to use `sys.schemas` table.
- For `[ObjectType]` it's better to use `obj.type_desc` only for `OBJECT_OR_COLUMN` permission class. For all other cases use `perm.[class_desc]`
- Another type of permission which is not handled so well with this query is `IMPERSONATE`. To get info about impersonations one should `LEFT JOIN` with `sys.database_principals` on `perm.major_id = imp.principal_id`
- With my experience it's better to replace `sys.login_token` with `sys.server_principals` as it will show also SQL Logins, not only Windows ones
- One should add `'G'` to allowed principal types to allow Windows groups
- Also, one can exclude users `sys` and `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` from resulting table, as these users are used only for service

I'll post first piece of script with all proposed fixes, other parts should be changed as well:

```
SELECT  
    [UserName] = ulogin.[name],
    [UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                    WHEN 'G' THEN 'Windows Group'
                 END,  
    [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],       
    [Role] = null,      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class] 
                        WHEN 1 THEN obj.type_desc               -- Schema-contained objects
                        ELSE perm.[class_desc]                  -- Higher-level objects
                   END,       
    [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class] 
                        WHEN 1 THEN OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id)  -- General objects
                        WHEN 3 THEN schem.[name]                -- Schemas
                        WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]                  -- Impersonations
                   END,
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --database user
    sys.database_principals princ  
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.server_principals ulogin on princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.schemas schem ON schem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.database_principals imp ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE 
    princ.[type] IN ('S','U','G') AND
    -- No need for these system accounts
    princ.[name] NOT IN ('sys', 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA')
```

Comment: Excellent feedback,  I plan on merging all feedback to the original answer.

Comment: Actually, there are couple more suggestions :) Alongside with object name should be schema name to easily identify current object. And there are more ways for someone to get access to objects via server roles: namely `sysadmin` + `securityadmin` are mapped as `dbo` for every DB on server + there is server permission `CONTROL SERVER` that could be granted to user. This permission gives almost same rights as being `sysadmin`.

Comment: Upon running this query I noticed it did not find db_datareader on one of the ids.  Although slow, the first answer seem more complete.

Comment: @Tequila this is the modification of the first piece of original query (all until first UNION); two other parts should be updated accordingly to get more complete answer

Answer (score 17):

The other answers that I have seen miss some permissions that are possible in the database. The first query in the code below will get the database level permission for **everything** that is not a system object. It generates the appropriate GRANT statements as well. The second query gets all the role meberships.

This has to be run for each database, but is too long to use with sp_MSforeachdb. If you want to do that you'd have to add it to the master database as a system stored procedure.

To cover all possibilities you'd also have to have a script that checks the server level permissions.

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS database_name
    , class
    , class_desc
    , major_id
    , minor_id
    , grantee_principal_id
    , grantor_principal_id
    , databasepermissions.type
    , permission_name
    , STATE
    , state_desc
    , granteedatabaseprincipal.name AS grantee_name
    , granteedatabaseprincipal.type_desc AS grantee_type_desc
    , granteeserverprincipal.name AS grantee_principal_name
    , granteeserverprincipal.type_desc AS grantee_principal_type_desc
    , grantor.name AS grantor_name
    , granted_on_name
    , permissionstatement + N' TO ' + QUOTENAME(granteedatabaseprincipal.name) + CASE 
        WHEN STATE = N'W'
            THEN N' WITH GRANT OPTION'
        ELSE N''
        END AS permissionstatement
FROM (
    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), DB_NAME())) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.class = 0)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.schemas.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(sys.objects.name) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON ' + QUOTENAME(sys.schemas.name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(sys.objects.name) + COALESCE(N' (' + QUOTENAME(sys.columns.name) + N')', N'') AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.objects
        ON sys.objects.object_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas
        ON sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.objects.schema_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.columns
        ON sys.columns.object_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
            AND sys.columns.column_id = sys.database_permissions.minor_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 1)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.schemas.name) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON SCHEMA::' + QUOTENAME(sys.schemas.name) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas
        ON sys.schemas.schema_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 3)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(targetPrincipal.name) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON ' + targetPrincipal.type_desc + N'::' + QUOTENAME(targetPrincipal.name) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS targetPrincipal
        ON targetPrincipal.principal_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 4)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.assemblies.name) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON ASSEMBLY::' + QUOTENAME(sys.assemblies.name) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.assemblies
        ON sys.assemblies.assembly_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 5)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.types.name) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON TYPE::' + QUOTENAME(sys.types.name) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.types
        ON sys.types.user_type_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 6)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.types.name) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON TYPE::' + QUOTENAME(sys.types.name) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.types
        ON sys.types.user_type_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 6)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.xml_schema_collections.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON XML SCHEMA COLLECTION::' + QUOTENAME(sys.xml_schema_collections.name) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.xml_schema_collections
        ON sys.xml_schema_collections.xml_collection_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 10)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.service_message_types.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON MESSAGE TYPE::' + QUOTENAME(sys.service_message_types.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.service_message_types
        ON sys.service_message_types.message_type_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 15)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.service_contracts.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON CONTRACT::' + QUOTENAME(sys.service_contracts.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.service_contracts
        ON sys.service_contracts.service_contract_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 16)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.services.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON SERVICE::' + QUOTENAME(sys.services.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.services
        ON sys.services.service_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 17)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.remote_service_bindings.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON REMOTE SERVICE BINDING::' + QUOTENAME(sys.remote_service_bindings.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.remote_service_bindings
        ON sys.remote_service_bindings.remote_service_binding_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 18)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.routes.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON ROUTE::' + QUOTENAME(sys.routes.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.routes
        ON sys.routes.route_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 19)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.symmetric_keys.name) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON ASYMMETRIC KEY::' + QUOTENAME(sys.symmetric_keys.name) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.symmetric_keys
        ON sys.symmetric_keys.symmetric_key_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 24)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.certificates.name) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON CERTIFICATE::' + QUOTENAME(sys.certificates.name) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.certificates
        ON sys.certificates.certificate_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 25)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT sys.database_permissions.class
        , sys.database_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.database_permissions.major_id
        , sys.database_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.database_permissions.type
        , sys.database_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.database_permissions.state
        , sys.database_permissions.state_desc
        , QUOTENAME(sys.asymmetric_keys.name) AS granted_on_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.database_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.database_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.database_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' ON ASYMMETRIC KEY::' + QUOTENAME(sys.asymmetric_keys.name) AS permissionstatement
    FROM sys.database_permissions
    INNER JOIN sys.asymmetric_keys
        ON sys.asymmetric_keys.asymmetric_key_id = sys.database_permissions.major_id
    WHERE (sys.database_permissions.major_id >= 0)
        AND (sys.database_permissions.class = 26)
    ) AS databasepermissions
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS granteedatabaseprincipal
    ON granteedatabaseprincipal.principal_id = grantee_principal_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals AS granteeserverprincipal
    ON granteeserverprincipal.sid = granteedatabaseprincipal.sid
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS grantor
    ON grantor.principal_id = grantor_principal_id
ORDER BY grantee_name, granted_on_name

SELECT roles.name AS role_name
    , roles.principal_id
    , roles.type AS role_type
    , roles.type_desc AS role_type_desc
    , roles.is_fixed_role AS role_is_fixed_role
    , memberdatabaseprincipal.name AS member_name
    , memberdatabaseprincipal.principal_id AS member_principal_id
    , memberdatabaseprincipal.type AS member_type
    , memberdatabaseprincipal.type_desc AS member_type_desc
    , memberdatabaseprincipal.is_fixed_role AS member_is_fixed_role
    , memberserverprincipal.name AS member_principal_name
    , memberserverprincipal.type_desc member_principal_type_desc
    , N'ALTER ROLE ' + QUOTENAME(roles.name) + N' ADD MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(memberdatabaseprincipal.name) AS AddRoleMembersStatement
FROM sys.database_principals AS roles
INNER JOIN sys.database_role_members
    ON sys.database_role_members.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS memberdatabaseprincipal
    ON memberdatabaseprincipal.principal_id = sys.database_role_members.member_principal_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.server_principals AS memberserverprincipal
    ON memberserverprincipal.sid = memberdatabaseprincipal.sid
ORDER BY role_name
    , member_name
```

UPDATE: The following queries will retrieve server level permissions and memberships.

```
SELECT sys.server_permissions.class
        , sys.server_permissions.class_desc
        , sys.server_permissions.major_id
        , sys.server_permissions.minor_id
        , sys.server_permissions.grantee_principal_id
        , sys.server_permissions.grantor_principal_id
        , sys.server_permissions.type
        , sys.server_permissions.permission_name
        , sys.server_permissions.state
        , sys.server_permissions.state_desc
        , granteeserverprincipal.name AS grantee_principal_name
        , granteeserverprincipal.type_desc AS grantee_principal_type_desc
        , grantorserverprinicipal.name AS grantor_name
        , CASE 
            WHEN sys.server_permissions.state = N'W'
                THEN N'GRANT'
            ELSE sys.server_permissions.state_desc
            END + N' ' + sys.server_permissions.permission_name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS + N' TO ' + QUOTENAME(granteeserverprincipal.name) AS permissionstatement
FROM sys.server_principals AS granteeserverprincipal
INNER JOIN sys.server_permissions
    ON sys.server_permissions.grantee_principal_id = granteeserverprincipal.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS grantorserverprinicipal
    ON grantorserverprinicipal.principal_id = sys.server_permissions.grantor_principal_id
ORDER BY granteeserverprincipal.name
    , sys.server_permissions.permission_name

SELECT roles.name AS server_role_name
    , roles.principal_id
    , roles.type AS role_type
    , roles.type_desc AS role_type_desc
    , roles.is_fixed_role AS role_is_fixed_role
    , memberserverprincipal.name AS member_principal_name
    , memberserverprincipal.principal_id AS member_principal_id
    , memberserverprincipal.type AS member_principal_type
    , memberserverprincipal.type_desc AS member_principal_type_desc
    , memberserverprincipal.is_fixed_role AS member_is_fixed_role
    , N'ALTER SERVER ROLE ' + QUOTENAME(roles.name) + N' ADD MEMBER ' + QUOTENAME(memberserverprincipal.name) AS AddRoleMembersStatement
FROM sys.server_principals AS roles
INNER JOIN sys.server_role_members
    ON sys.server_role_members.role_principal_id = roles.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.server_principals AS memberserverprincipal
    ON memberserverprincipal.principal_id = sys.server_role_members.member_principal_id
WHERE roles.type = N'R'
ORDER BY server_role_name
    , member_principal_name
```

Comment: This has proven to be the best answer of them all. Just one small edit: the symmetric key section, under the database permissions, generates the permission statement with 'ON ASYMMETRIC KEY' rather than 'ON SYMMETRIC KEY'. Awesome job, @JamieSee!

Answer (score 12):

Awesome script [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059579/1501497) and contributors! Thanks!

I have a s-ton of users, so running this for all users was a nightmare. I couldn't add comments, so I am posting the whole script with the changes. I added a variable + where clause so I can search for anything matching up to 5 characters in the user name (or all users when left blank). Nothing special, but I thought it would be helpful in some use cases.

```
DECLARE @p_userName NVARCHAR(5) = 'UName' -- Specify up to five characters here (or none for all users)

/*
Security Audit Report
1) List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group directly 
2) List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
3) List all access provisioned to the public role

Columns Returned:
UserName        : SQL or Windows/Active Directory user cccount.  This could also be an            Active Directory group.
UserType        : Value will be either 'SQL User' or 'Windows User'.  This reflects the type of user defined for the  SQL Server user account.
DatabaseUserName: Name of the associated user as defined in the database user account.  The database user may not be the same as the server user.
Role            : The role name.  This will be null if the associated permissions to the object are defined at directly on the user account, otherwise this will be the name of the role that the user is a member of.
PermissionType  : Type of permissions the user/role has on an object. Examples could include CONNECT, EXECUTE, SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, ALTER, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP, VIEW DEFINITION, etc. This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission definitions.
PermissionState : Reflects the state of the permission type, examples could include GRANT, DENY, etc. This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission definitions.
ObjectType      : Type of object the user/role is assigned permissions on.  Examples could include USER_TABLE, SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION, SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION, SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE, VIEW, etc. This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission definitions.          
ObjectName      : Name of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on. This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission definitions.
ColumnName      : Name of the column of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on. This value is only populated if the object is a table, view or a table value function. 

*/

DECLARE @userName NVARCHAR(4) = @p_UserName + '%'
--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group directly 

SELECT  
[UserName] = CASE princ.[type] 
                WHEN 'S' THEN princ.[name]
                WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
             END,
[UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
             END,  
[DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],       
[Role] = null,      
[PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
[PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
[ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],       
[ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
[ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
--database user
sys.database_principals princ  
LEFT JOIN
--Login accounts
sys.login_token ulogin on princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
--Permissions
sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
--Table columns
sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE 
princ.[type] in ('S','U')  
AND princ.[name] LIKE @userName  -- Added this line --CSLAGLE
UNION
--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
SELECT  
[UserName] = CASE memberprinc.[type] 
                WHEN 'S' THEN memberprinc.[name]
                WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
             END,
[UserType] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
             END, 
[DatabaseUserName] = memberprinc.[name],   
[Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
[PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
[PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
[ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],   
[ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
[ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
--Role/member associations
sys.database_role_members members
JOIN
--Roles
sys.database_principals roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
JOIN
--Role members (database users)
sys.database_principals memberprinc ON memberprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
--Login accounts
sys.login_token ulogin on memberprinc.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
--Permissions
sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
--Table columns
sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE memberprinc.[name] LIKE @userName -- Added this line --CSLAGLE
UNION
--List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
SELECT  
[UserName] = '{All Users}', 
[UserType] = '{All Users}', 
[DatabaseUserName] = '{All Users}',       
[Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
[PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
[PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
[ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],  
[ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
[ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
--Roles
sys.database_principals roleprinc
LEFT JOIN        
--Role permissions
sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
--Table columns
sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]                   
JOIN 
--All objects   
sys.objects obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE
--Only roles
roleprinc.[type] = 'R' AND
--Only public role
roleprinc.[name] = 'public' AND
--Only objects of ours, not the MS objects
obj.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY
princ.[Name],
OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
col.[name],
perm.[permission_name],
perm.[state_desc],
obj.type_desc--perm.[class_desc]
```

Comment: You have a bug in your assignment logic. DECLARE @ userName NVARCHAR(4) = @ p_UserName + '%'  -- this is assigning a NVARCHAR(5) + VARCHAR(1) to an NVARCHAR(4).   So you should be DECLARE @ userName NVARCHAR(6)

Answer (score 11):

Here is my version, adapted from others.  I spent 30 minutes just now trying to remember how I came up with this, and [@Jeremy 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059579/1501497) seems to be the core inspiration.  I didn't want to update [Jeremy's answer,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059579/1501497) just in case I introduced bugs, so I am posting my version of it here.

I suggest pairing the full script with some inspiration taken from [Kenneth Fisher's T-SQL Tuesday: What Permissions Does a Specific User Have?](https://sqlstudies.com/2014/11/11/tsql-tuesday-60-something-new-learned-what-permissions-does-have/): This will allow you to answer compliance/audit questions bottom-up, as opposed to top-down.

```
EXECUTE AS LOGIN = '<loginname>'
 
SELECT token.name AS GroupNames
FROM sys.login_token token
JOIN sys.server_principals grp
    ON token.sid = grp.sid
WHERE token.[type] = 'WINDOWS GROUP'
  AND grp.[type] = 'G'
 
REVERT
```

To understand what this covers, consider `Contoso\DB_AdventureWorks_Accounting` Windows AD Group with member `Contoso\John.Doe`.  John.Doe authenticates to AdventureWorks via server_principal `Contoso\DB_AdventureWorks_Logins` Windows AD Group.  If someone asks you, "What permissions does John.Doe have?", you cannot answer that question with just the below script.  You need to then iterate through each row returned by the below script and join it to the above script.  (You may also need to normalize for stale `name` values via looking up the SID in your Active Directory provider.)

Here is the script, without incorporating such reverse look-up logic.

```
/*


--Script source found at :  http://stackoverflow.com/a/7059579/1387418
Security Audit Report
1) List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group directly 
2) List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
3) List all access provisioned to the public role



Columns Returned:
UserName         : SQL or Windows/Active Directory user account.  This could also be an Active Directory group.
UserType         : Value will be either 'SQL User' or 'Windows User'.  This reflects the type of user defined for the 
                  SQL Server user account.
PrinciaplUserName: if UserName is not blank, then UserName else DatabaseUserName
PrincipalType    : Possible values are 'SQL User', 'Windows User', 'Database Role', 'Windows Group'
DatabaseUserName : Name of the associated user as defined in the database user account.  The database user may not be the
                   same as the server user.
Role             : The role name.  This will be null if the associated permissions to the object are defined at directly
                   on the user account, otherwise this will be the name of the role that the user is a member of.
PermissionType   : Type of permissions the user/role has on an object. Examples could include CONNECT, EXECUTE, SELECT
                   DELETE, INSERT, ALTER, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP, VIEW DEFINITION, etc.
                   This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                   definitions.
PermissionState  : Reflects the state of the permission type, examples could include GRANT, DENY, etc.
                   This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                   definitions.
ObjectType       : Type of object the user/role is assigned permissions on.  Examples could include USER_TABLE, 
                   SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION, SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION, SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE, VIEW, etc.   
                   This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                   definitions.          
ObjectName       : Name of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on.  
                   This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                   definitions.
ColumnName       : Name of the column of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on. This value
                   is only populated if the object is a table, view or a table value function.                 
*/

DECLARE @HideDatabaseDiagrams BIT = 1;

--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group directly 
SELECT  
    [UserName] = CASE dbprinc.[type] 
                    WHEN 'S' THEN dbprinc.[name] -- SQL User
                    WHEN 'U' THEN sprinc.[name] -- Windows User
                    WHEN 'R' THEN NULL -- Database Role
                    WHEN 'G' THEN NULL -- Windows Group
                    ELSE NULL
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE dbprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                    WHEN 'R' THEN NULL -- Database Role
                    WHEN 'G' THEN NULL -- Windows Group
                    ELSE dbprinc.[type]
                 END,
    [PrincipalUserName] = COALESCE(
                    CASE dbprinc.[type]
                        WHEN 'S' THEN dbprinc.[name] -- SQL User
                        WHEN 'U' THEN sprinc.[name] -- Windows User
                        WHEN 'R' THEN NULL -- Database Role
                        WHEN 'G' THEN NULL -- Windows Group
                        ELSE NULL
                     END,
                     dbprinc.[name]
                 ),
    [PrincipalType] = CASE dbprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                    WHEN 'R' THEN 'Database Role'
                    WHEN 'G' THEN 'Windows Group'
                 END,
    [DatabaseUserName] = dbprinc.[name],
    [Role] = null,
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],
    [ObjectType] = obj.[type_desc],--perm.[class_desc],
    [ObjectSchema] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --database user
    sys.database_principals dbprinc  
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.server_principals sprinc on dbprinc.[sid] = sprinc.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = dbprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE 
    dbprinc.[type] in ('S','U')
    AND CASE
        WHEN @HideDatabaseDiagrams = 1 AND
        dbprinc.[name] = 'guest'
        AND (
            (
                obj.type_desc = 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION'
                AND OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id) = 'fn_diagramobjects'
            )
            OR (
                obj.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
                AND OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id) IN
                (
                    N'sp_alterdiagram',
                    N'sp_creatediagram',
                    N'sp_dropdiagram',
                    N'sp_helpdiagramdefinition',
                    N'sp_helpdiagrams',
                    N'sp_renamediagram'
                )
            )
        )
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END = 1
UNION
--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
SELECT  
    [UserName] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN memberprinc.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN sprinc.[name]
                    WHEN 'R' THEN NULL -- Database Role
                    WHEN 'G' THEN NULL -- Windows Group
                    ELSE NULL
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                    WHEN 'R' THEN NULL -- Database Role
                    WHEN 'G' THEN NULL -- Windows Group
                 END, 
    [PrincipalUserName] = COALESCE(
                    CASE memberprinc.[type]
                        WHEN 'S' THEN memberprinc.[name]
                        WHEN 'U' THEN sprinc.[name]
                        WHEN 'R' THEN NULL -- Database Role
                        WHEN 'G' THEN NULL -- Windows Group
                        ELSE NULL
                     END,
                     memberprinc.[name]
                 ),
    [PrincipalType] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                    WHEN 'R' THEN 'Database Role'
                    WHEN 'G' THEN 'Windows Group'
                 END, 
    [DatabaseUserName] = memberprinc.[name],
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],
    [ObjectSchema] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --Role/member associations
    sys.database_role_members members
JOIN
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
JOIN
    --Role members (database users)
    sys.database_principals memberprinc ON memberprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.server_principals sprinc on memberprinc.[sid] = sprinc.[sid]
LEFT JOIN
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE    
    CASE
        WHEN @HideDatabaseDiagrams = 1 AND
        memberprinc.[name] = 'guest'
        AND (
            (
                obj.type_desc = 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION'
                AND OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id) = 'fn_diagramobjects'
            )
            OR (
                obj.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
                AND OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id) IN
                (
                    N'sp_alterdiagram',
                    N'sp_creatediagram',
                    N'sp_dropdiagram',
                    N'sp_helpdiagramdefinition',
                    N'sp_helpdiagrams',
                    N'sp_renamediagram'
                )
            )
        )
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END = 1
UNION
--List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
SELECT  
    [UserName] = '{All Users}',
    [UserType] = '{All Users}',
    [PrincipalUserName] = '{All Users}',
    [PrincipalType] = '{All Users}',
    [DatabaseUserName] = '{All Users}',
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],
    [ObjectSchema] = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc
LEFT JOIN        
    --Role permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
JOIN 
    --All objects
    sys.objects obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE
    --Only roles
    roleprinc.[type] = 'R' AND
    --Only public role
    roleprinc.[name] = 'public' AND
    --Only objects of ours, not the MS objects
    obj.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND CASE
        WHEN @HideDatabaseDiagrams = 1 AND
        roleprinc.[name] = 'public'
        AND (
            (
                obj.type_desc = 'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION'
                AND OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id) = 'fn_diagramobjects'
            )
            OR (
                obj.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
                AND OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id) IN
                (
                    N'sp_alterdiagram',
                    N'sp_creatediagram',
                    N'sp_dropdiagram',
                    N'sp_helpdiagramdefinition',
                    N'sp_helpdiagrams',
                    N'sp_renamediagram'
                )
            )
        )
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END = 1
ORDER BY
    dbprinc.[Name],
    OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    col.[name],
    perm.[permission_name],
    perm.[state_desc],
    obj.type_desc--perm.[class_desc]
```

Answer (score 8):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_permission 
AS 
    DECLARE @db_name  VARCHAR(200), 
            @sql_text VARCHAR(max) 

    SET @sql_text='Create table ##db_name (user_name varchar(max),' 

    DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT name 
      FROM   sys.databases 

    OPEN db_cursor 

    FETCH next FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
      BEGIN 
          SET @sql_text=@sql_text + @db_name + ' varchar(max),' 

          FETCH next FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name 
      END 

    CLOSE db_cursor 

    SET @sql_text=@sql_text + 'Server_perm varchar(max))' 

    EXEC (@sql_text) 

    DEALLOCATE db_cursor 

    DECLARE @RoleName VARCHAR(50) 
    DECLARE @UserName VARCHAR(50) 
    DECLARE @CMD VARCHAR(1000) 

    CREATE TABLE #permission 
      ( 
         user_name    VARCHAR(50), 
         databasename VARCHAR(50), 
         role         VARCHAR(50) 
      ) 

    DECLARE longspcur CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT name 
      FROM   sys.server_principals 
      WHERE  type IN ( 'S', 'U', 'G' ) 
             AND principal_id > 4 
             AND name NOT LIKE '##%' 
             AND name <> 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM' 
             AND name <> 'ONDEMAND\Administrator' 
             AND name NOT LIKE 'steel%' 

    OPEN longspcur 

    FETCH next FROM longspcur INTO @UserName 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
      BEGIN 
          CREATE TABLE #userroles_kk 
            ( 
               databasename VARCHAR(50), 
               role         VARCHAR(50) 
            ) 

          CREATE TABLE #rolemember_kk 
            ( 
               dbrole     VARCHAR(100), 
               membername VARCHAR(100), 
               membersid  VARBINARY(2048) 
            ) 

          SET @CMD = 'use ? truncate table #RoleMember_kk insert into #RoleMember_kk exec sp_helprolemember  insert into #UserRoles_kk (DatabaseName, Role) select db_name(), dbRole from #RoleMember_kk where MemberName = ''' + @UserName + '''' 

          EXEC Sp_msforeachdb 
            @CMD 

          INSERT INTO #permission 
          SELECT @UserName 'user', 
                 b.name, 
                 u.role 
          FROM   sys.sysdatabases b 
                 LEFT OUTER JOIN #userroles_kk u 
                              ON u.databasename = b.name --and u.Role='db_owner' 
          ORDER  BY 1 

          DROP TABLE #userroles_kk; 

          DROP TABLE #rolemember_kk; 

          FETCH next FROM longspcur INTO @UserName 
      END 

    CLOSE longspcur 

    DEALLOCATE longspcur 

    TRUNCATE TABLE ##db_name 

    DECLARE @d1 VARCHAR(max), 
            @d2 VARCHAR(max), 
            @d3 VARCHAR(max), 
            @ss VARCHAR(max) 
    DECLARE perm_cur CURSOR FOR 
      SELECT * 
      FROM   #permission 
      ORDER  BY 2 DESC 

    OPEN perm_cur 

    FETCH next FROM perm_cur INTO @d1, @d2, @d3 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
      BEGIN 
          IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                        FROM   ##db_name 
                        WHERE  user_name = @d1) 
            BEGIN 
                SET @ss='insert into ##db_name(user_name) values (''' 
                        + @d1 + ''')' 

                EXEC (@ss) 

                SET @ss='update ##db_name set ' + @d2 + '=''' + @d3 
                        + ''' where user_name=''' + @d1 + '''' 

                EXEC (@ss) 
            END 
          ELSE 
            BEGIN 
                DECLARE @var            NVARCHAR(max), 
                        @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(max), 
                        @var1           NVARCHAR(max) 

                SET @var = N'select @var1=' + @d2 
                           + ' from ##db_name where USER_NAME=''' + @d1 
                           + ''''; 
                SET @ParmDefinition = N'@var1 nvarchar(300) OUTPUT'; 

                EXECUTE Sp_executesql 
                  @var, 
                  @ParmDefinition, 
                  @var1=@var1 output; 

                SET @var1=Isnull(@var1, ' ') 
                SET @var= '  update ##db_name set ' + @d2 + '=''' + @var1 + ' ' 
                          + @d3 + ''' where user_name=''' + @d1 + '''  ' 

                EXEC (@var) 
            END 

          FETCH next FROM perm_cur INTO @d1, @d2, @d3 
      END 

    CLOSE perm_cur 

    DEALLOCATE perm_cur 

    SELECT * 
    FROM   ##db_name 

    DROP TABLE ##db_name 

    DROP TABLE #permission
```

Comment: This one is nice. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The GetPermissions Stored Procedure above is good however it uses Sp_msforeachdb which means that it will break if your SQL Instance has any databases names that include spaces or dashes and other non-best-practices characters.  I have created a version that avoids the use of Sp_msforeachdb and also includes two columns that indicate 1 - if the Login is a sysadmin login (IsSysAdminLogin) and 2 - if the login is an orphan user (IsEmptyRow).

```
USE [master] ;
GO
IF EXISTS
(
    SELECT * FROM sys.objects
    WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.uspGetPermissionsOfAllLogins_DBsOnColumns')
    AND [type] in (N'P',N'PC')
)
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetPermissionsOfAllLogins_DBsOnColumns ;
END
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.uspGetPermissionsOfAllLogins_DBsOnColumns
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
;
BEGIN TRY
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE id = object_id(N'[tempdb].dbo.[#permission]')
    )
    DROP TABLE #permission
    ;
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE id = object_id(N'[tempdb].dbo.[#userroles_kk]')
    )
    DROP TABLE #userroles_kk
    ;
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE id = object_id(N'[tempdb].dbo.[#rolemember_kk]')
    )
    DROP TABLE #rolemember_kk
    ;
    IF EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects
        WHERE id = object_id(N'[tempdb].dbo.[##db_name]')
    )
    DROP TABLE ##db_name
    ;
    DECLARE
    @db_name VARCHAR(255)
    ,@sql_text VARCHAR(MAX) 
    ;
    SET @sql_text =
    'CREATE TABLE ##db_name
    (
        LoginUserName VARCHAR(MAX)
        ,' 
    ;
    DECLARE cursDBs CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT [name]
        FROM sys.databases
        ORDER BY [name]
    ;
    OPEN cursDBs 
    ;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursDBs INTO @db_name 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
        BEGIN 
                SET @sql_text =
        @sql_text + QUOTENAME(@db_name) + ' VARCHAR(MAX)
        ,' 
                FETCH NEXT FROM cursDBs INTO @db_name 
        END 
    CLOSE cursDBs 
    ;
    SET @sql_text =
        @sql_text + 'IsSysAdminLogin CHAR(1)
        ,IsEmptyRow CHAR(1)
    )' 

    --PRINT @sql_text
    EXEC (@sql_text)
    ;
    DEALLOCATE cursDBs 
    ;
    DECLARE
    @RoleName VARCHAR(255) 
    ,@UserName VARCHAR(255) 
    ;
    CREATE TABLE #permission 
    (
     LoginUserName VARCHAR(255)
     ,databasename VARCHAR(255)
     ,[role] VARCHAR(255)
    ) 
    ;
    DECLARE cursSysSrvPrinName CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT [name]
        FROM sys.server_principals 
        WHERE
        [type] IN ( 'S', 'U', 'G' )
        AND principal_id > 4
        AND [name] NOT LIKE '##%'
        ORDER BY [name]
    ;
    OPEN cursSysSrvPrinName
    ;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursSysSrvPrinName INTO @UserName 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        CREATE TABLE #userroles_kk 
        ( 
             databasename VARCHAR(255)
             ,[role] VARCHAR(255)
        ) 
        ;
        CREATE TABLE #rolemember_kk 
        ( 
             dbrole VARCHAR(255)
             ,membername VARCHAR(255)
             ,membersid VARBINARY(2048)
        ) 
        ;
        DECLARE cursDatabases CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR
        SELECT [name]
        FROM sys.databases
        ORDER BY [name]
        ;
        OPEN cursDatabases
        ;
        DECLARE 
        @DBN VARCHAR(255)
        ,@sqlText NVARCHAR(4000)
        ;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursDatabases INTO @DBN
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @sqlText =
    N'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@DBN) + ';
    TRUNCATE TABLE #RoleMember_kk 
    INSERT INTO #RoleMember_kk 
    EXEC sp_helprolemember 
    INSERT INTO #UserRoles_kk
    (DatabaseName,[Role])
    SELECT db_name(),dbRole
    FROM #RoleMember_kk
    WHERE MemberName = ''' + @UserName + '''
    '

            --PRINT @sqlText ;
            EXEC sp_executesql @sqlText ;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursDatabases INTO @DBN
        END
        CLOSE cursDatabases
        ;
        DEALLOCATE cursDatabases
        ;
        INSERT INTO #permission 
        SELECT
        @UserName 'user'
        ,b.name
        ,u.[role]
        FROM
        sys.sysdatabases b
        LEFT JOIN
        #userroles_kk u 
            ON QUOTENAME(u.databasename) = QUOTENAME(b.name)
        ORDER  BY 1 
        ;
        DROP TABLE #userroles_kk
        ; 
        DROP TABLE #rolemember_kk
        ;
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursSysSrvPrinName INTO @UserName 
    END 
    CLOSE cursSysSrvPrinName 
    ;
    DEALLOCATE cursSysSrvPrinName 
    ;
    TRUNCATE TABLE ##db_name 
    ;
    DECLARE
    @d1 VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@d2 VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@d3 VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@ss VARCHAR(MAX)
    ;
    DECLARE cursPermisTable CURSOR FOR
        SELECT * FROM #permission 
        ORDER BY 2 DESC 
    ;
    OPEN cursPermisTable
    ;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursPermisTable INTO @d1,@d2,@d3
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN 
        IF NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM ##db_name WHERE LoginUserName = @d1
        )
        BEGIN 
            SET @ss =
            'INSERT INTO ##db_name(LoginUserName) VALUES (''' + @d1 + ''')' 
            EXEC (@ss) 
            ;
            SET @ss =
            'UPDATE ##db_name SET ' + @d2 + ' = ''' + @d3 + ''' WHERE LoginUserName = ''' + @d1 + '''' 
            EXEC (@ss)
            ;
        END 
        ELSE 
        BEGIN 
            DECLARE
            @var NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,@ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ,@var1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
            ;
            SET @var =
            N'SELECT @var1 = ' + QUOTENAME(@d2) + ' FROM ##db_name WHERE LoginUserName = ''' + @d1 + ''''
            ; 
            SET @ParmDefinition =
            N'@var1 NVARCHAR(600) OUTPUT '
            ; 
            EXECUTE Sp_executesql @var,@ParmDefinition,@var1 = @var1 OUTPUT
            ;
            SET @var1 =
            ISNULL(@var1, ' ')
            ;
            SET @var =
            '  UPDATE ##db_name SET ' + @d2 + '=''' + @var1 + ' ' + @d3 + ''' WHERE LoginUserName = ''' + @d1 + '''  '
            ;
            EXEC (@var)
            ;
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM cursPermisTable INTO @d1,@d2,@d3
    END 
    CLOSE cursPermisTable
    ;
    DEALLOCATE cursPermisTable 
    ;
    UPDATE ##db_name SET
    IsSysAdminLogin = 'Y'
    FROM
    ##db_name TT
    INNER JOIN
    dbo.syslogins SL
        ON TT.LoginUserName = SL.[name]
    WHERE
    SL.sysadmin = 1
    ;
    DECLARE cursDNamesAsColumns CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR
    SELECT [name]
    FROM tempdb.sys.columns
    WHERE
    OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##db_name')
    AND [name] NOT IN ('LoginUserName','IsEmptyRow')
    ORDER BY [name]
    ;
    OPEN cursDNamesAsColumns
    ;
    DECLARE 
    @ColN VARCHAR(255)
    ,@tSQLText NVARCHAR(4000)
    ;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursDNamesAsColumns INTO @ColN
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @tSQLText =
N'UPDATE ##db_name SET
IsEmptyRow = ''N''
WHERE IsEmptyRow IS NULL
AND ' + QUOTENAME(@ColN) + ' IS NOT NULL
;
'

        --PRINT @tSQLText ;
        EXEC sp_executesql @tSQLText ;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cursDNamesAsColumns INTO @ColN
    END
    CLOSE cursDNamesAsColumns
    ;
    DEALLOCATE cursDNamesAsColumns
    ;
    UPDATE ##db_name SET
    IsEmptyRow = 'Y'
    WHERE IsEmptyRow IS NULL
    ;
    UPDATE ##db_name SET
    IsSysAdminLogin = 'N'
    FROM
    ##db_name TT
    INNER JOIN
    dbo.syslogins SL
        ON TT.LoginUserName = SL.[name]
    WHERE
    SL.sysadmin = 0
    ;
    SELECT * FROM ##db_name
    ;
    DROP TABLE ##db_name
    ;
    DROP TABLE #permission
    ;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE
    @cursDBs_Status INT
    ,@cursSysSrvPrinName_Status INT
    ,@cursDatabases_Status INT
    ,@cursPermisTable_Status INT
    ,@cursDNamesAsColumns_Status INT
    ;
    SELECT
    @cursDBs_Status = CURSOR_STATUS('GLOBAL','cursDBs')
    ,@cursSysSrvPrinName_Status = CURSOR_STATUS('GLOBAL','cursSysSrvPrinName')
    ,@cursDatabases_Status = CURSOR_STATUS('GLOBAL','cursDatabases')
    ,@cursPermisTable_Status = CURSOR_STATUS('GLOBAL','cursPermisTable')
    ,@cursDNamesAsColumns_Status = CURSOR_STATUS('GLOBAL','cursPermisTable')
    ;
    IF @cursDBs_Status > -2
        BEGIN
            CLOSE cursDBs ;
            DEALLOCATE cursDBs ;
        END
    IF @cursSysSrvPrinName_Status > -2
        BEGIN
            CLOSE cursSysSrvPrinName ;
            DEALLOCATE cursSysSrvPrinName ;
        END
    IF @cursDatabases_Status > -2
        BEGIN
            CLOSE cursDatabases ;
            DEALLOCATE cursDatabases ;
        END
    IF @cursPermisTable_Status > -2
        BEGIN
            CLOSE cursPermisTable ;
            DEALLOCATE cursPermisTable ;
        END
    IF @cursDNamesAsColumns_Status > -2
        BEGIN
            CLOSE cursDNamesAsColumns ;
            DEALLOCATE cursDNamesAsColumns ;
        END
    SELECT ErrorNum = ERROR_NUMBER(),ErrorMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE() ;
END CATCH
GO
/*
EXEC [master].dbo.uspGetPermissionsOfAllLogins_DBsOnColumns ;
*/
```

Comment: According to [user himanshu](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3508611/himanshu) `you can use [] to resolve it.
sp_msforeachdb ' use [?] select db_name()' ` I assume that his answer was meant as a comment but since his account does not fullfill the min-reputation he posted an answer instead.

Comment: Agreed with threeFourOneSixOneThree. Using sp_foreachdb or sp_foreachtable will work fine when brackets are in place.

Answer (score 6):

Great thanks for awesome audit scripts.

I highly recommend for audit user use awesome Kenneth Fisher ([b](http://sqlstudies.com/) | [t](https://twitter.com/sqlstudent144)) stored procedures:

- [sp_DBPermissions](https://github.com/sqlstudent144/SQL-Server-Scripts/blob/master/sp_DBPermissions.sql)
- [sp_SrvPermissions](https://github.com/sqlstudent144/SQL-Server-Scripts/blob/master/sp_SrvPermissions.sql)

Comment: Dead links in 2019

Comment: @gbeaven links fixed

Comment: I use a combination of Kenneth Fisher's scripts and the script I posted below.  The script I posted below is outputted in a format that is easy to slice and dice in Excel.  I use Redgate SSMS plug-in and Open in Excel feature to export my results to Excel, then apply Quick Filter.

Kenneth's tool is more useful for zooming in on a particular  principal or role.

Answer (score 6):

Due to low rep can't reply with this to the people asking to run this on multiple databases/SQL Servers.

Create a registered server group and query across them all us the following and just cursor through the databases:

```
--Make sure all ' are doubled within the SQL string.

DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(50)   
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(max)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR 
LOCAL FAST_FORWARD
FOR  
SELECT name
FROM MASTER.dbo.sysdatabases
where name like '%DBName%'

OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

SELECT @statement = 'use '+@dbname +';'+ '
/*
Security Audit Report
1) List all access provisioned to a SQL user or Windows user/group directly
2) List all access provisioned to a SQL user or Windows user/group through a database or application role
3) List all access provisioned to the public role

Columns Returned:
UserType        : Value will be either ''SQL User'', ''Windows User'', or ''Windows Group''.
                  This reflects the type of user/group defined for the SQL Server account.
DatabaseUserName: Name of the associated user as defined in the database user account.  The database user may not be the
                  same as the server user.
LoginName       : SQL or Windows/Active Directory user account.  This could also be an Active Directory group.
Role            : The role name.  This will be null if the associated permissions to the object are defined at directly
                  on the user account, otherwise this will be the name of the role that the user is a member of.
PermissionType  : Type of permissions the user/role has on an object. Examples could include CONNECT, EXECUTE, SELECT
                  DELETE, INSERT, ALTER, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP, VIEW DEFINITION, etc.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
PermissionState : Reflects the state of the permission type, examples could include GRANT, DENY, etc.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
ObjectType      : Type of object the user/role is assigned permissions on.  Examples could include USER_TABLE,
                  SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION, SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION, SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE, VIEW, etc.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
Schema          : Name of the schema the object is in.
ObjectName      : Name of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
ColumnName      : Name of the column of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on. This value
                  is only populated if the object is a table, view or a table value function.
*/

    --1) List all access provisioned to a SQL user or Windows user/group directly
    SELECT
        [UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                         WHEN ''S'' THEN ''SQL User''
                         WHEN ''U'' THEN ''Windows User''
                         WHEN ''G'' THEN ''Windows Group''
                     END,
        [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],
        [LoginName]        = ulogin.[name],
        [Role]             = NULL,
        [PermissionType]   = perm.[permission_name],
        [PermissionState]  = perm.[state_desc],
        [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc]        -- Schema-contained objects
                           ELSE perm.[class_desc]             -- Higher-level objects
                       END,
        [Schema] = objschem.[name],
        [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name]       -- Schemas
                           WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]             -- Impersonations
                           ELSE OBJECT_NAME(perm.[major_id])  -- General objects
                       END,
        [ColumnName] = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Database user
        sys.database_principals            AS princ
        --Login accounts
        LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals    AS ulogin    ON ulogin.[sid] = princ.[sid]
        --Permissions
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions AS perm      ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.objects              AS obj       ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS objschem  ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
        --Table columns
        LEFT JOIN sys.columns              AS col       ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                           AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
        --Impersonations
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals  AS imp       ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE
        princ.[type] IN (''S'',''U'',''G'')
        -- No need for these system accounts
        AND princ.[name] NOT IN (''sys'', ''INFORMATION_SCHEMA'')

UNION

    --2) List all access provisioned to a SQL user or Windows user/group through a database or application role
    SELECT
        [UserType] = CASE membprinc.[type]
                         WHEN ''S'' THEN ''SQL User''
                         WHEN ''U'' THEN ''Windows User''
                         WHEN ''G'' THEN ''Windows Group''
                     END,
        [DatabaseUserName] = membprinc.[name],
        [LoginName]        = ulogin.[name],
        [Role]             = roleprinc.[name],
        [PermissionType]   = perm.[permission_name],
        [PermissionState]  = perm.[state_desc],
        [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc]        -- Schema-contained objects
                           ELSE perm.[class_desc]             -- Higher-level objects
                       END,
        [Schema] = objschem.[name],
        [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name]       -- Schemas
                           WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]             -- Impersonations
                           ELSE OBJECT_NAME(perm.[major_id])  -- General objects
                       END,
        [ColumnName] = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Role/member associations
        sys.database_role_members          AS members
        --Roles
        JOIN      sys.database_principals  AS roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
        --Role members (database users)
        JOIN      sys.database_principals  AS membprinc ON membprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
        --Login accounts
        LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals    AS ulogin    ON ulogin.[sid] = membprinc.[sid]
        --Permissions
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions AS perm      ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.objects              AS obj       ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS objschem  ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
        --Table columns
        LEFT JOIN sys.columns              AS col       ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                           AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
        --Impersonations
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals  AS imp       ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE
        membprinc.[type] IN (''S'',''U'',''G'')
        -- No need for these system accounts
        AND membprinc.[name] NOT IN (''sys'', ''INFORMATION_SCHEMA'')

UNION

    --3) List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
    SELECT
        [UserType]         = ''{All Users}'',
        [DatabaseUserName] = ''{All Users}'',
        [LoginName]        = ''{All Users}'',
        [Role]             = roleprinc.[name],
        [PermissionType]   = perm.[permission_name],
        [PermissionState]  = perm.[state_desc],
        [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc]        -- Schema-contained objects
                           ELSE perm.[class_desc]             -- Higher-level objects
                       END,
        [Schema] = objschem.[name],
        [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name]       -- Schemas
                           WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]             -- Impersonations
                           ELSE OBJECT_NAME(perm.[major_id])  -- General objects
                       END,
        [ColumnName] = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Roles
        sys.database_principals            AS roleprinc
        --Role permissions
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions AS perm      ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
        --All objects
        JOIN      sys.objects              AS obj       ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS objschem  ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
        --Table columns
        LEFT JOIN sys.columns              AS col       ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                           AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
        --Impersonations
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals  AS imp       ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE
        roleprinc.[type] = ''R''
        AND roleprinc.[name] = ''public''
        AND obj.[is_ms_shipped] = 0

ORDER BY
    [UserType],
    [DatabaseUserName],
    [LoginName],
    [Role],
    [Schema],
    [ObjectName],
    [ColumnName],
    [PermissionType],
    [PermissionState],
    [ObjectType]
'
exec sp_executesql @statement

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @dbname  
END  
CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

This thread massively helped me thanks everyone!

Comment: This helped me tremendously today. The only thing I changed was to output the database name as well (as I ran the query for multiple databases), using `DB_NAME()` and store the output in a temp table to avoid ending up with multiple results sets. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I just added the following to [Jeremy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059579/1501497) because I had a role assigned to the database db_datareader which wasn't showing the permissions that role had.  I tried going through all of the answers in everyone's posts but couldn't find anything that would do this so I added my own query.

```
    SELECT 
    UserType='Role', 
    DatabaseUserName = '{Role Members}',
    LoginName = DP2.name,
    Role = DP1.name,
    'SELECT' AS [PermissionType] ,
    [PermissionState]  = 'GRANT',
    [ObjectType] = 'Table',
    [Schema] = 'dbo',
    [ObjectName] = 'All Tables',
    [ColumnName] = NULL
FROM sys.database_role_members AS DRM  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP1  
    ON DRM.role_principal_id = DP1.principal_id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.database_principals AS DP2  
    ON DRM.member_principal_id = DP2.principal_id  
WHERE DP1.type = 'R'
AND DP2.name IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's the most popular answer submitted by [Jeremy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7059579/1501497), but modified to include the sysadmin and disabled flags mentioned by Greg Sipes as well as a log_date_time column.

Best of both worlds?

```
/*
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database


Security Audit Report
1) List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group directly 
2) List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
3) List all access provisioned to the public role

Columns Returned:
UserName        : SQL or Windows/Active Directory user account.  This could also be an Active Directory group.
UserType        : Value will be either 'SQL User' or 'Windows User'.  This reflects the type of user defined for the 
                  SQL Server user account.
DatabaseUserName: Name of the associated user as defined in the database user account.  The database user may not be the
                  same as the server user.
Role            : The role name.  This will be null if the associated permissions to the object are defined at directly
                  on the user account, otherwise this will be the name of the role that the user is a member of.
PermissionType  : Type of permissions the user/role has on an object. Examples could include CONNECT, EXECUTE, SELECT
                  DELETE, INSERT, ALTER, CONTROL, TAKE OWNERSHIP, VIEW DEFINITION, etc.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
PermissionState : Reflects the state of the permission type, examples could include GRANT, DENY, etc.
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
ObjectType      : Type of object the user/role is assigned permissions on.  Examples could include USER_TABLE, 
                  SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION, SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION, SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE, VIEW, etc.   
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.          
ObjectName      : Name of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on.  
                  This value may not be populated for all roles.  Some built in roles have implicit permission
                  definitions.
ColumnName      : Name of the column of the object that the user/role is assigned permissions on. This value
                  is only populated if the object is a table, view or a table value function.                 
*/

--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group directly 
SELECT  
    [UserName] = CASE princ.[type] 
                    WHEN 'S' THEN princ.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                 END,  
    [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],       
    [Role] = null,      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],       
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name],
    sp.is_disabled,
    s.sysadmin,
    GETDATE() AS [log_date_time]
FROM    
    --database user
    sys.database_principals princ  
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins s ON princ.sid = s.sid
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON princ.name = sp.name
WHERE 
    princ.[type] in ('S','U')
UNION
--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
SELECT  
    [UserName] = CASE memberprinc.[type] 
                    WHEN 'S' THEN memberprinc.[name]
                    WHEN 'U' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                    WHEN 'S' THEN 'SQL User'
                    WHEN 'U' THEN 'Windows User'
                 END, 
    [DatabaseUserName] = memberprinc.[name],   
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],   
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name],
    sp.is_disabled,
    s.sysadmin,
    GETDATE() AS [log_date_time]
FROM    
    --Role/member associations
    sys.database_role_members members
JOIN
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
JOIN
    --Role members (database users)
    sys.database_principals memberprinc ON memberprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on memberprinc.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins s ON memberprinc.[sid] = s.sid
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON memberprinc.[name] = sp.name
UNION
--List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
SELECT  
    [UserName] = '{All Users}',
    [UserType] = '{All Users}', 
    [DatabaseUserName] = '{All Users}',       
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],  
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name],
    sp.is_disabled,
    s.sysadmin,
    GETDATE() AS [log_date_time]
FROM    
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc
LEFT JOIN        
    --Role permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]     
LEFT JOIN sys.syslogins s ON roleprinc.sid = s.sid
LEFT JOIN sys.server_principals sp ON roleprinc.name = sp.name
JOIN 
    --All objects   
    sys.objects obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE
    --Only roles
    roleprinc.[type] = 'R' AND
    --Only public role
    roleprinc.[name] = 'public' AND
    --Only objects of ours, not the MS objects
    obj.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY
    princ.[Name],
    OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    col.[name],
    perm.[permission_name],
    perm.[state_desc],
    obj.type_desc--perm.[class_desc]
```

Comment: Good update,  thanks @Ryan Bradley.

Answer (score 3):

I tried just about all of these but I quickly noticed that some were missing, especially sysadmin users. Having a hole like that won't look good in our upcoming audit, so this is what I came up with

```
USE master
GO

SELECT DISTINCT 
        p.name AS [loginname] ,
        --p.type,
        p.type_desc ,
        p.is_disabled,
        s.sysadmin,
        sp.permission_name
FROM sys.server_principals p
INNER JOIN sys.syslogins s ON p.sid = s.sid
INNER JOIN sys.server_permissions sp ON p.principal_id = sp.grantee_principal_id
WHERE p.type_desc IN ('SQL_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_LOGIN', 'WINDOWS_GROUP')
    -- Logins that are not process logins
    AND p.name NOT LIKE '##%'
ORDER BY p.name
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple query that shows only whether you are a SysAdmin or not :

```
IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin') = 1  
   print 'Current user''s login is a member of the sysadmin role'  
ELSE IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin') = 0  
   print 'Current user''s login is NOT a member of the sysadmin role'  
ELSE IF IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin') IS NULL  
   print 'ERROR: The server role specified is not valid.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I couldn't comment on the Sean Rose post due to insufficient reputation, however I had to amend the "public" role portion of the script as it didn't show SCHEMA-scoped permissions due to the (INNER) JOIN against sys.objects.  After that was changed to a LEFT JOIN I further had to amend the WHERE-clause logic to omit system objects.  My amended query for the public perms is below.

```
--3) List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
    SELECT
        @@servername ServerName
        , db_name() DatabaseName
        , [UserType]         = '{All Users}',
        [DatabaseUserName] = '{All Users}',
        [LoginName]        = '{All Users}',
        [Role]             = roleprinc.[name],
        [PermissionType]   = perm.[permission_name],
        [PermissionState]  = perm.[state_desc],
        [ObjectType] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 1 THEN obj.[type_desc]        -- Schema-contained objects
                           ELSE perm.[class_desc]             -- Higher-level objects
                       END,
        [Schema] = objschem.[name],
        [ObjectName] = CASE perm.[class]
                           WHEN 3 THEN permschem.[name]       -- Schemas
                           WHEN 4 THEN imp.[name]             -- Impersonations
                           ELSE OBJECT_NAME(perm.[major_id])  -- General objects
                       END,
        [ColumnName] = col.[name]
    FROM
        --Roles
        sys.database_principals            AS roleprinc
        --Role permissions
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_permissions AS perm      ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS permschem ON permschem.[schema_id] = perm.[major_id]
        --All objects
        LEFT JOIN sys.objects              AS obj       ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
        LEFT JOIN sys.schemas              AS objschem  ON objschem.[schema_id] = obj.[schema_id]
        --Table columns
        LEFT JOIN sys.columns              AS col       ON col.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
                                                           AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
        --Impersonations
        LEFT JOIN sys.database_principals  AS imp       ON imp.[principal_id] = perm.[major_id]
    WHERE
        roleprinc.[type] = 'R'
        AND roleprinc.[name] = 'public'
        AND isnull(obj.[is_ms_shipped], 0) = 0
        AND isnull(object_schema_name(perm.[major_id]), '') <> 'sys'

ORDER BY
    [UserType],
    [DatabaseUserName],
    [LoginName],
    [Role],
    [Schema],
    [ObjectName],
    [ColumnName],
    [PermissionType],
    [PermissionState],
    [ObjectType]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want check access to databases for a particular login has use this simple script as below:

sys.sp_helplogins @LoginNamePattern = 'Domain\login' -- sysname

Answer (score 0):

--ok my turn to contribute back,enjoy

This report header dynamically grabs the SQL Instance name, date\time, and account name the report is run by, all things a good auditor will want to know. :)

Note - if you have a extended property called 'environment' on the Master database, the value (whatever you use:  PreProd, Development, Production, DR, etc)  will be included in the report header.

```
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SELECT 'See Messages Tab..... use  Ctrl+SHIFT+F and re-run to ''send to file'''
    DECLARE @DBName nvarchar(2000) = DB_NAME()
    DECLARE @User_Name nvarchar(200) = suser_sname()
    DECLARE @Account_Name nvarchar(200)
    DECLARE @Granted_permissions nvarchar(2000)
    DECLARE @Permission_State nvarchar(200)
    DECLARE @ParentObject nvarchar(200)
    DECLARE @env2 varchar(50) = Convert(varchar(50),(Select ServerProperty('Servername')));
    DECLARE @day varchar(50) = FORMAT (getdate(), 'dddd, MM, yyyy');
    DECLARE @clk varchar(50) = FORMAT (getdate(), 'hh:mm:ss tt') ;
    DECLARE @env1 VARCHAR(25) = (SELECT CAST(value AS varchar(25)) 
    FROM [master].[sys].fn_listextendedproperty('environment', default, default, default, default, default, default));

    PRINT '*** ' + @DBName + ' Security Audit Report ***';
    PRINT '      in the ' + @env1 + ' environment'; 
    PRINT '      on SQL Instance: ' + @env2;  
    PRINT '      '+ @day + ' at ' + @clk;
    PRINT '      run under account ' + @User_Name;
    PRINT ' '

    CREATE TABLE #GP(
        DBName NVARCHAR(200),
        Account_Name NVARCHAR(200),
        Granted_Permissions NVARCHAR(max),
        Permission_State NVARCHAR(200),
        ParentObject NVARCHAR(200)
        )
    ;WITH SampleDataR AS
        (SELECT
            DB_NAME() AS 'DBName'
            ,dp.name AS 'Account_Name'
            ,dpm.permission_name AS 'Granted_Permissions'
            ,dpm.state_desc AS 'Permission_State'
            ,dpm.class_desc AS 'ParentObject'
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DB_NAME(), dp.[name] ,dpm.state_desc, dpm.class_desc ORDER BY permission_name) rownum
        FROM sys.database_principals dp
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [sys].[database_permissions] dpm
            ON dp.principal_id = dpm.grantee_principal_id
        WHERE dp.type ='R'
        AND dp.sid IS NOT NULL
        AND dp.name <> 'public' 
        AND dp.name NOT LIKE 'db_a%'
        AND dp.name NOT LIKE 'db_b%'
        AND dp.name NOT LIKE 'db_d%'
        AND dp.name NOT LIKE 'db_o%'
        AND dp.name NOT LIKE 'db_s%'
        --AND dpm.class_desc = 'DATABASE'  -- remove to see schema based permissions
        ) 

        --Select * from SampleDataR

    INSERT INTO #GP
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        DBName
        ,Account_Name
        ,(SELECT Granted_Permissions + 
            CASE 
                WHEN s1.rownum = (select MAX(rownum) 
                FROM SampleDataR 
                WHERE DBName = s1.DBName AND 
                Account_Name = s1.Account_Name AND
                ParentObject = s1.ParentObject)
                THEN ' (' + Permission_State + '), '
                ELSE ' (' + Permission_State + '),  '
            END 
    FROM SampleDataR s1
    WHERE s1.DBName = s2.DBName AND 
          s1.Account_Name = s2.Account_Name AND
          s1.ParentObject = s2.ParentObject
        FOR xml path(''),type).value('(.)[1]','varchar(max)'
        ) Granted_Permissions
        ,Permission_State
        ,ParentObject
        FROM SampleDataR s2

        --Select * from #GP

    PRINT  'Assigned Role Permissions'
    PRINT ' '
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DISTINCT DBName, Account_Name, ParentObject, Granted_permissions 
        FROM #GP

    OPEN cur
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DBname, @Account_Name, @ParentObject, @Granted_permissions;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN   
            PRINT @DBName + ', ' + @Account_Name +  ', ' + '[' + @ParentObject + '], ' + @Granted_permissions
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DBname, @Account_Name,  @ParentObject , @Granted_permissions;
        END
    CLOSE cur;
    DEALLOCATE cur;
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DROP Table #GP

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @DBName2 nvarchar(200)
    DECLARE @Account_Name2 nvarchar(200)
    DECLARE @Granted_permissions2 nvarchar(200)

    CREATE TABLE #GP2(
        DBName NVARCHAR(200),
        Account_Name NVARCHAR(200) ,
        Granted_Permissions NVARCHAR(200)
        )
    ;WITH SampleDataR AS
        (SELECT
            DB_NAME() AS 'DBName'
            ,dp.name AS 'Account_Name'
            --,dp.type
            ,dpm.permission_name
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DB_NAME(), dp.[name] ORDER BY permission_name) rownum
        FROM sys.database_principals dp
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [sys].[database_permissions] dpm
            ON dp.principal_id = dpm.grantee_principal_id
                --order by dp.type
        WHERE dp.type not in ('A', 'R', 'X') --removed  'G',
        AND dp.sid is not null
        AND dp.name not in ('guest','dbo')
        ) 
    INSERT INTO #GP2 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        DBName
        ,Account_Name
        ,(SELECT permission_name + 
            CASE 
                WHEN s1.rownum = (select MAX(rownum) 
                FROM SampleDataR 
                WHERE DBName = s1.DBName and Account_Name = s1.Account_Name
            )
            THEN '' 
            ELSE ',' 
            END 
    FROM SampleDataR s1
    WHERE s1.DBName = s2.DBName AND s1.Account_Name = s2.Account_Name
        FOR xml path(''),type).value('(.)[1]','varchar(max)') Granted_Permissions
        FROM SampleDataR s2;

    PRINT ' '
    PRINT ' '
    PRINT  'Assigned User Permissions'
    PRINT ' '
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DBName, Account_Name, Granted_permissions 
        FROM #GP2
    OPEN cur
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DBname2, @Account_Name2, @Granted_permissions2;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN   
            PRINT @DBName2 + ', ' + @Account_Name2 + ', ' + @Granted_permissions2
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DBname2, @Account_Name2, @Granted_permissions2;
        END
    CLOSE cur;
    DEALLOCATE cur;
    DROP TABLE #GP2

    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @DBName3 nvarchar(200)
    DECLARE @Role_Name3 nvarchar(max)
    DECLARE @Members3 nvarchar(max)

    CREATE TABLE #GP3(
        DBName NVARCHAR(200),
        Role_Name NVARCHAR(max),
        members NVARCHAR(max)
        )
    ;WITH SampleDataR AS
        (SELECT
            DB_NAME() AS 'DBName'
            ,r.name AS 'role_name'
            ,m.name AS 'members'
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DB_NAME(), r.[name] ORDER BY m.[name]) rownum
        FROM sys.database_role_members rm 
            INNER JOIN sys.database_principals r on rm.role_principal_id = r.principal_id
            INNER JOIN sys.database_principals m on rm.member_principal_id = m.principal_id
        ) 

    INSERT INTO #GP3
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        DBName
        ,Role_Name
        ,(SELECT Members + 
            CASE 
                WHEN s3.rownum = (select MAX(rownum) 
                FROM SampleDataR 
                WHERE DBName = s3.DBName and Role_Name = s3.Role_Name
                )
            THEN ',' 
            ELSE ',' 
            END 
    FROM SampleDataR s1
    WHERE s1.DBName = s3.DBName and s1.Role_Name = s3.Role_Name
        FOR xml path(''),type).value('(.)[1]','varchar(max)') Members
        FROM SampleDataR s3

    PRINT ' '
    PRINT ' '
    PRINT  'Assigned Role Membership'
    PRINT ' '
    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        SELECT DBName, Role_Name, Members 
        FROM #GP3
    OPEN cur
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DBname3, @Role_Name3, @Members3;
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN   
            PRINT @DBName3 + ', ' + @Role_Name3 + ', ' + @Members3
            FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @DBname3, @Role_Name3, @Members3;
        END
    CLOSE cur;
    DEALLOCATE cur;
    DROP Table #GP3;
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH  
   SELECT 'Real ERROR at Line #' + CAST(ERROR_LINE() AS VARCHAR(20));
   -- Throw/raise and error caught from the Try section. 
   THROW; 
END CATCH;
```

END

--great to save as a stored proc

Answer (score 0):

Extract db role membership

```
select user_name(DRM.member_principal_id) [DatabaseUser]
   ,user_name(DRM.role_principal_id) [DatabaseRole]
   ,DP.type_desc as [UserType]
   ,'Exec sp_addrolemember '''+ user_name(DRM.role_principal_id)+ ''','
   + '''' + user_name(DRM.member_principal_id)+'''' [Command To Add Role Members]
from sys.database_role_members DRM
inner join sys.database_principals DP on DRM.member_principal_id=DP.principal_id
where DRM.member_principal_id>1
Order by DatabaseUser
```