# In SQL Server, what is the difference between a user query and a system query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-performance, sqlperformance

The documentation for [sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345421.aspx) uses the terms "user queries" and "system queries" but it doesn't define what those mean. For example:

- user_seeks: "Number of seeks caused by **user queries** that the recommended index in the group could have been used for."
- system_seeks: "Number of seeks caused by **system queries**, such as auto stats queries, that the recommended index in the group could have been used for."

Based on the way the term is used at [System query to determine full (including inherited from AD ROLES) view of permissions in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107853/system-query-to-determine-full-including-inherited-from-ad-roles-view-of-permi), I assume that system queries are queries against [system tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179932.aspx). Then user queries must be queries against [user tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406.aspx).

Does anyone have a more authoritative source for the definition of these two terms? I'm asking because I'm using the results from sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats and considering how to properly weigh avg_user_impact vs. avg_system_impact in deciding whether to apply an index.

Comment: I think user queries are that a user executes on a sql server and a system query is the query that sql server runs [behind the scene tasks]. If you ever run a trace you will see how much work sql server has to do just to keep a sql server instance running, even when no user is executing any queries on the server.

Comment: I haven't seen the term used that way. For example, there's a script called "SQL Azure System Queries" at https://sqlserverperformance.wordpress.com/2010/09/29/a-small-selection-of-sql-azure-system-queries/ that contains a bunch of SELECTs against sys.* tables. But the SQL Server documentation never comes out and actually defines the term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the answer to the question [What causes system_scans in sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats to count up?](https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/17922/what-causes-system-scans-in-sysdm-db-index-usage-s.html)

> I understand the system scans/lookups columns are to do with
>   statistics updates & index maintenance. I asked Brent Ozar when he was
>   presenting over in Germany about a month ago and he confirmed this for
>   me.
>
> I asked him about this with regard to identifying unused indexes on a
>   system. He said that you only have to be concerned with User Lookups
>   and User Scans, the system ones are really only system side
>   operations. So an index that only has "system" activity has not been
>   used by queries since the index usage statistics were last reset.

I confirmed this partially by running some queries on `AdventureWorks2012`:

```
/* Get the statistics from Sales.SalesOrderHeader */
EXEC sp_helpstats 'Sales.SalesOrderHeader'

-- Results: 
/*
statistics_name             statistics_keys
-------------------------------------------
_WA_Sys_00000004_4B7734FF   DueDate
_WA_Sys_00000008_4B7734FF   SalesOrderNumber
_WA_Sys_0000000D_4B7734FF   TerritoryID
_WA_Sys_0000000E_4B7734FF   BillToAddressID
_WA_Sys_0000000F_4B7734FF   ShipToAddressID
_WA_Sys_00000010_4B7734FF   ShipMethodID
_WA_Sys_00000011_4B7734FF   CreditCardID
_WA_Sys_00000013_4B7734FF   CurrencyRateID
*/

/* Update the statistics for the SalesOrderNumber stats */
UPDATE STATISTICS Sales.SalesOrderHeader _WA_Sys_00000008_4B7734FF WITH FULLSCAN

/* Get the index usage stats for that index */
SELECT
    DB_NAME(iu.database_id),
    OBJECT_NAME(iu.object_id),
    i.name,
    iu.user_seeks,
    iu.user_scans,
    iu.system_seeks,
    iu.system_scans
FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats iu
JOIN sys.indexes i 
    ON iu.object_id = i.object_id
    AND iu.index_id = i.index_id
WHERE i.name = 'AK_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderNumber'

/*
DatabaseName        TableName           IndexName                               
AdventureWorks2012  SalesOrderHeader    AK_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderNumber    

user_seeks  user_scans  system_seeks    system_scans
0           0           0               1
*/

/* Seek and scan the index */
SELECT SalesOrderNumber
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader
WHERE SalesOrderNumber = N'A'
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 100 SalesOrderNumber
FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader WITH (INDEX(AK_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderNumber))

/* 
Running the index usage query from above returns the following: 

DatabaseName        TableName           IndexName                               
AdventureWorks2012  SalesOrderHeader    AK_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderNumber    

user_seeks  user_scans  system_seeks    system_scans
1           1           0               1
*/

/* Rebuild the index to remove all usage stats */
ALTER INDEX AK_SalesOrderHeader_SalesOrderNumber ON Sales.SalesOrderHeader REBUILD
```

So user seeks and scans appearing the usage management view seem appropriate, and the system scan from updating the statistics matches the answer given above.

But back to the original question, I would say you don't need to worry about system seeks and system scans on `sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats`. It seems like they would signify that SQL Server was attempting to look up some type of its own meta data and not having the correct internal indexes to satisfy the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Way Back before SQL 4.21 we always referred to system queries as stored procs that were in the master database and user queries were in user databases (not master).

The reason had to do with naming conventions and search algorithms for where the "global" code in the master database was. (sp_MyCode  vs. spMyCode)

Also eXtended stored procs were defined in master as well.

I do not think this is what people mean anymore by the terms.