# How to figure out list of users who have access to a given object in DB?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to figure out the query that can be used to get list of all users who have read and or write access to a given object, schema or db in SQL Server 2012. I know that it is impossible to know all users because some users are given access through AD groups, that is why I'm planning to get final list of users from Active Directory once I know list of AD groups.

I have looked at [SQL Server query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database) question but it is too general, I need to know specific SQL or Windows Logins that have access.

I have came up with the following query but not sure if my logic is correct.

```
SELECT u.name AS UserName
       ,o.name AS ObjectName
       ,o.type_desc AS ObjectType
       ,d.class_desc
       ,d.permission_name
       ,d.state
       ,d.state_desc
    FROM sys.database_permissions AS d
    JOIN sys.objects AS o
        ON d.major_id = o.parent_object_id
    JOIN sys.sysusers AS u
        ON d.grantee_principal_id = u.uid
           AND u.issqlrole = 0
    WHERE o.type_desc = 'USER_TABLE'
        AND o.name = 'MyTableName'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Script out permissions to all objects for a specific DB user 

DECLARE @DatabaseUserName [sysname]
SET @DatabaseUserName = 'domain\user-- Add whatever user name here 

SET NOCOUNT ON`enter code here`
DECLARE
@errStatement [varchar](8000),
@msgStatement [varchar](8000),
@DatabaseUserID [smallint],
@ServerUserName [sysname],
@RoleName [varchar](8000),
@ObjectID [int],
@ObjectName [varchar](261)

SELECT
@DatabaseUserID = [sysusers].[uid],
@ServerUserName = [master].[dbo].[syslogins].[loginname]
FROM [dbo].[sysusers]
INNER JOIN [master].[dbo].[syslogins]
ON [sysusers].[sid] = [master].[dbo].[syslogins].[sid]
WHERE [sysusers].[name] = @DatabaseUserName
IF @DatabaseUserID IS NULL
BEGIN
SET @errStatement = 'User ' + @DatabaseUserName + ' does not exist in ' + DB_NAME() + CHAR(13) +
'Please provide the name of a current user in ' + DB_NAME() + ' you wish to script.'
RAISERROR(@errStatement, 16, 1)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SET @msgStatement = '--Security creation script for user ' + @ServerUserName + CHAR(13) +
'--Created At: ' + CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 112) + REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 108), ':', '') + CHAR(13) +
'--Created By: ' + SUSER_NAME() + CHAR(13) +
'--Add User To Database' + CHAR(13) +
'USE [' + DB_NAME() + ']' + CHAR(13) +
'EXEC [sp_grantdbaccess]' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@loginame = ''' + @ServerUserName + ''',' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@name_in_db = ''' + @DatabaseUserName + '''' + CHAR(13) +
'GO' + CHAR(13) +
'--Add User To Roles'
PRINT @msgStatement
DECLARE _sysusers
CURSOR
LOCAL
FORWARD_ONLY
READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT
[name]
FROM [dbo].[sysusers]
WHERE
[uid] IN
(
SELECT
[groupuid]
FROM [dbo].[sysmembers]
WHERE [memberuid] = @DatabaseUserID
)
OPEN _sysusers
FETCH
NEXT
FROM _sysusers
INTO @RoleName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @msgStatement = 'EXEC [sp_addrolemember]' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@rolename = ''' + @RoleName + ''',' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + '@membername = ''' + @DatabaseUserName + ''''
PRINT @msgStatement
FETCH
NEXT
FROM _sysusers
INTO @RoleName
END
SET @msgStatement = 'GO' + CHAR(13) +
'--Set Object Specific Permissions'
PRINT @msgStatement
DECLARE _sysobjects
CURSOR
LOCAL
FORWARD_ONLY
READ_ONLY
FOR
SELECT
DISTINCT([sysobjects].[id]),
'[' + USER_NAME([sysobjects].[uid]) + '].[' + [sysobjects].[name] + ']'
FROM [dbo].[sysprotects]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[sysobjects]
ON [sysprotects].[id] = [sysobjects].[id]
WHERE [sysprotects].[uid] = @DatabaseUserID
OPEN _sysobjects
FETCH
NEXT
FROM _sysobjects
INTO
@ObjectID,
@ObjectName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
SET @msgStatement = ''
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 193 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'SELECT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 195 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'INSERT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 197 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'UPDATE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 196 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'DELETE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 224 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'EXECUTE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 26 AND [protecttype] = 205)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'REFERENCES,'
IF LEN(@msgStatement) > 0
BEGIN
IF RIGHT(@msgStatement, 1) = ','
SET @msgStatement = LEFT(@msgStatement, LEN(@msgStatement) - 1)
SET @msgStatement = 'GRANT' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + @msgStatement + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'ON ' + @ObjectName + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'TO ' + @DatabaseUserName
PRINT @msgStatement
END
SET @msgStatement = ''
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 193 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'SELECT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 195 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'INSERT,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 197 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'UPDATE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 196 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'DELETE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 224 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'EXECUTE,'
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [dbo].[sysprotects] WHERE [id] = @ObjectID AND [uid] = @DatabaseUserID AND [action] = 26 AND [protecttype] = 206)
SET @msgStatement = @msgStatement + 'REFERENCES,'
IF LEN(@msgStatement) > 0
BEGIN
IF RIGHT(@msgStatement, 1) = ','
SET @msgStatement = LEFT(@msgStatement, LEN(@msgStatement) - 1)
SET @msgStatement = 'DENY' + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + @msgStatement + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'ON ' + @ObjectName + CHAR(13) +
CHAR(9) + 'TO ' + @DatabaseUserName
PRINT @msgStatement
END
FETCH
NEXT
FROM _sysobjects
INTO
@ObjectID,
@ObjectName
END
CLOSE _sysobjects
DEALLOCATE _sysobjects
PRINT 'GO'
END
```