# Stored procedure to return user permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to make a stored procedure to return all permissions for a input user and I have no idea how to return all permissions.

Any suggestions are welcome,
Thanks!

Comment: There more than one kind of thing within SQL Server that could be called a "permission", which do you mean?  Give us some examples.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database)

Comment: Have you tried anything like [googling](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=3erPU93AB8HH8gfSxYLYCA&gws_rd=ssl#q=get%20sql%20server%20user%20permissions) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Get_User_Permissions
@UserName VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT   pc.name            AS [User Name]
            ,pc.type_desc       AS [User Type]
            ,pm.permission_name AS [Permission Name]
            ,pm.state_desc      AS [Permission Status]
            ,pm.class_desc      AS [Object Type]
            ,object_name(pm.major_id) AS [object_Name]
    FROM sys.database_principals pc
    LEFT JOIN  sys.database_permissions pm
    ON pm.grantee_principal_id = pc.principal_id
    WHERE pr.name = @UserName
END
```

Comment: Thanks M.Ali ,sorry for my bad question,i'm new here.Have a good day.