# SQL SERVER equivalent for Oracle all_users and user_roles_privs

Tags: sql-server, oracle, database-migration

what would be the SQL SERVER 2012 equivalent for Oracle `all_users`  and `user_roles_privs` tables please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: There are two 'leves' of 'users' in SQL Server. The first one is the `Server Logins`. These are the users who can connect to the server. The second 'level' are the `Database Users` (these users are mapped to Server Logins).

Also there are two types of privileges: Server level privileges and Database (object) level privileges.

These are the relevant catalog views:

- Server logins: `sys.server_principals` and `sys.sql_logins` and `sys.login_token`
- Database users: `sys.database_principals`
- Database permissions: `sys.database_permissions`
- Database role memberships: `sys.database_role_members`

You can use these functions too to check if a user has privilege:
[`fn_my_permissions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx) and [`HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189802.aspx)

You can read more about catalog views on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx

Also, please check this question: [SQL Server query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database)