# List all the effective permissions (with users/roles) of a given object?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How list all the users/roles with granted permission(s) to a object, e.g. a view, a schema?

```
GetUserRolePermissions 'dbo.AView'
GetUserRolePermissions 'aSchema'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database)

Comment: The link doesn't return the effective permissions. Please remove the link.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9 : I deleted my answer. Even my updated plan won't get the perspective of each role, which in some cases is all that there is. Getting effective permissions is complicated by needing to consider role/database/schema/object permissions and include the `DENY`s and maybe impersonation. It's possible but I don't have time to do it now, but will put it on my growing to-do list ;-). One thing to consider with regards to starting at the object instead of the user: different users can be in different combinations of roles, so what the roles themselves can do doesn't tell the whole story.