# Checking if user has access to the snapshot agent using Windows credentials

Tags: c#, sql-server, replication, snapshot

I am currently working on replication using snapshot agent. I am using windows integrated security to connect to the db.

Within my c# application i need to check if the user has permissions to run the snapshot agent using their active directory permissions.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Cheers

Comment: There's an answer about how to get all security permissions in SQL server here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database . I'm sure you can study the query results and filter the one you want :-)

Comment: Cheers will have a read but not sure how this works with windows authentication

Comment: I'm admittedly no expert, but AFAIK, every windows user allowed to be authenticated should have a corresponding login account in the SQL Server database, wouldn't it? Permissions for that login is what you should be checking, if i'm not mistaken. There's T-SQL's `SUSER_NAME()` to find the current login