# To find database names, users and permissions

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me with a script to find out the database names, names of users, role names and permissions of users in an instance in SQL Server 2012?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find out the database names

```
EXEC sp_helpdb; 
--OR 
EXEC sp_Databases;
```

names of users (logins)

```
--Server logins:
SELECT * FROM sys.server_principals
```

role names

```
--Database principals:
SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals
```

For more see this page [SQL Server query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database)

## Update#1

```
USE tempdb

IF object_id('##table') is not null
    DROP TABLE ##table


CREATE TABLE ##table (
    db nvarchar(100),
    Username nvarchar(100),
    UserType nvarchar(100),
    DatabaseUserName nvarchar(100),
    [Role] nvarchar(100),      
    PermissionType nvarchar(100),       
    PermissionState nvarchar(100), 
    ObjectType nvarchar(100),       
    ObjectName nvarchar(100),
    ColumnName nvarchar(100)
)



DECLARE @databasess TABLE (dbname nvarchar(50))

INSERT INTO @databasess
SELECT name
from sys.databases

DECLARE @DBN nVARCHAR(100)
        ,@sqlText NVARCHAR(max)
        ,@sql NVARCHAR(max)
        ,@n int = 0
        ,@i int = 0

SET @sqlText = 
'--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group directly 
SELECT  
    [db] = DB_NAME(),
    [UserName] = CASE princ.[type] 
                    WHEN '+CHAR(39)+'S'+CHAR(39)+' THEN princ.[name]
                    WHEN '+CHAR(39)+'U'+CHAR(39)+' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE princ.[type]
                    WHEN '+CHAR(39)+'S'+CHAR(39)+' THEN '+CHAR(39)+'SQL User'+CHAR(39)+'
                    WHEN '+CHAR(39)+'U'+CHAR(39)+' THEN '+CHAR(39)+'Windows User'+CHAR(39)+'
                 END,  
    [DatabaseUserName] = princ.[name],       
    [Role] = null,      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],       
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --database user
    sys.database_principals princ  
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on princ.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = princ.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col ON col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
WHERE 
    princ.[type] in ('+CHAR(39)+'S'+CHAR(39)+','+CHAR(39)+'U'+CHAR(39)+')
UNION
--List all access provisioned to a sql user or windows user/group through a database or application role
SELECT  
    [db] = DB_NAME(),
    [UserName] = CASE memberprinc.[type] 
                    WHEN '+CHAR(39)+'S'+CHAR(39)+' THEN memberprinc.[name]
                    WHEN '+CHAR(39)+'U'+CHAR(39)+' THEN ulogin.[name] COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
                 END,
    [UserType] = CASE memberprinc.[type]
                    WHEN '+CHAR(39)+'S'+CHAR(39)+' THEN '+CHAR(39)+'SQL User'+CHAR(39)+'
                    WHEN '+CHAR(39)+'U'+CHAR(39)+' THEN '+CHAR(39)+'Windows User'+CHAR(39)+'
                 END, 
    [DatabaseUserName] = memberprinc.[name],   
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],   
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --Role/member associations
    sys.database_role_members members
JOIN
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc ON roleprinc.[principal_id] = members.[role_principal_id]
JOIN
    --Role members (database users)
    sys.database_principals memberprinc ON memberprinc.[principal_id] = members.[member_principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Login accounts
    sys.login_token ulogin on memberprinc.[sid] = ulogin.[sid]
LEFT JOIN        
    --Permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]
LEFT JOIN
    sys.objects obj ON perm.[major_id] = obj.[object_id]
UNION
--List all access provisioned to the public role, which everyone gets by default
SELECT 
    [db] = DB_NAME(),
    [UserName] = '+CHAR(39)+'{All Users}'+CHAR(39)+',
    [UserType] = '+CHAR(39)+'{All Users}'+CHAR(39)+', 
    [DatabaseUserName] = '+CHAR(39)+'{All Users}'+CHAR(39)+',       
    [Role] = roleprinc.[name],      
    [PermissionType] = perm.[permission_name],       
    [PermissionState] = perm.[state_desc],       
    [ObjectType] = obj.type_desc,--perm.[class_desc],  
    [ObjectName] = OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    [ColumnName] = col.[name]
FROM    
    --Roles
    sys.database_principals roleprinc
LEFT JOIN        
    --Role permissions
    sys.database_permissions perm ON perm.[grantee_principal_id] = roleprinc.[principal_id]
LEFT JOIN
    --Table columns
    sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = perm.major_id 
                    AND col.[column_id] = perm.[minor_id]                   
JOIN 
    --All objects   
    sys.objects obj ON obj.[object_id] = perm.[major_id]
WHERE
    --Only roles
    roleprinc.[type] = '+CHAR(39)+'R'+CHAR(39)+' AND
    --Only public role
    roleprinc.[name] = '+CHAR(39)+'public'+CHAR(39)+' AND
    --Only objects of ours, not the MS objects
    obj.is_ms_shipped = 0
ORDER BY
    princ.[Name],
    OBJECT_NAME(perm.major_id),
    col.[name],
    perm.[permission_name],
    perm.[state_desc],
    obj.type_desc--perm.[class_desc]'

SELECT @n = COUNT(*)
FROM @databasess

WHILE @n > @i
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @DBN = dbname FROM @databasess

    SET @sql = 'USE '+@DBN +' '+@sqlText

    INSERT INTO ##table
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
    set @i = @i+1
    DELETE FROM @databasess WHERE dbname = @DBN
END

SELECT * 
FROM ##table
```

Comment: I want a script that combines all this.. I already knew about these queries.

Comment: I have edited script, it takes all database names in `@databasess` table and than runs the big script (from the page which I gave you a link in my answer) that writes data in `##table`. In the end it shows all the data you needed.