# How to check certain attributes for a USER in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to find the table in which I can check if a user is enabled or disabled. For example if I were to execute this command

```
use Database
Go
Revoke Connect from "DomainName\abcdef"
```

The changes are probably reflected in one of the tables, I would like to know which one. **I AM *NOT*** interested in the change in the GUI (i.e SSMS)

Also I would like to know whether the **User Login Policies** are ***enforced or not***, by knowing which table these attributes are in.

I have successfully found the table for a Login(server) i.e.

```
sys.sql_logins
```

I need to find it for a **USER** of a single database.

Comment: Looked at `sys.sysusers`?

Comment: There's an excellent answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database