# Checking Truncate/Alter Permission for a login

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter

How to check whether a login has `truncate` permission for a particular table?

We have a login called `Test` for which we have given `ALTER` permission to particular tables alone. Now I want get the list of tables for which `Test` login has `Alter` permission.

Checked in google and forum couldn't find any answer.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database

Comment: @sagi - Thanks, the link did help me to find the answer but not exactly what i was looking for. Will post answer soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you have the ability to impersonate the user, you can do the following:

```
execute as user = 'Test';

select p.*
from sys.tables as t
cross apply sys.fn_my_permissions(t.name, 'OBJECT') as p
    where permission_name = 'ALTER';

revert;
```

Comment: Could not find login details in above query

Comment: Did you read/understand the code? Or did you just copy and paste it into your Management Studio Window and run it? If the latter without the former, that's a really dangerous habit. You have to change the name of the user that you're impersonating in order to get the permissions for that user. I've updated the code accordingly

Comment: Extremely sorry didn't read your answer properly.. One of my worst day at office.. Executed with proper user and it showed exactly what I am looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to list out the permissions against a particular user ,Try out with the below query.

```
SELECT  OBJECT_NAME(major_id) TableName,PERMISSION_NAME, STATE_DESC,  U.name UserName 
FROM sys.database_permissions P 
    JOIN sys.tables T ON P.major_id = T.object_id 
    JOIN sysusers U ON U.uid = P.grantee_principal_id
WHERE U.name='Test'
```

[image]

Comment: It is not returning any result

Comment: @prdp : i tried,its working..please see the screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following function as well to quickly check the permissions that are available for a specific user.

MS SQL [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx) that will give you some useful information on its usage is provided in the link.

**Syntax:**

```
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_my_permissions('TEST', 'USER');
```