# Unable to manually access columns in SQL Server 2008 in Object Explorer

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table called '**employees**', with column names '**Employee_Number**', '**Location**', '**Salary**' and '**Birthday**'.

On the left of the Management Studio page, under the Object Explorer, there are the options to view the *Columns*, *Keys*, *Constraints*, etc. of my '**employees**' table.

Each option expands when double-clicked, except the 'Columns' tab. Apparently, the table does not have any columns in it. I have checked to see if my table is still there, using `SELECT * FROM employees;`. From which, all columns are shown.

I wanted to access one of these columns manually, so I can rename it, without using code. Why is the Columns section of the Object Explorer returning no values?

All keys and constraints I had made on the table are still there on Object Explorer.

Comment: Is your user/login/group denied VIEW DEFINITION permission on that table/schema/database/instance? Although I would have thought that would have prevented you from seeing the "components" other than columns too... might be better placed to ask this over at [DBA.se](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I used to be able to view the Columns before. I must have pressed something, now that it appears blank.

Comment: Could you have simply lost connection or something? Have you tried disconnecting/reconnecting object explorer?

Comment: I have logged off the system and logged back on. No difference.

Comment: Try checking your permissions then - something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database

Comment: So, I just copy and paste that massive bit of quote and run it to check the permissions?

Comment: Yeah and look to see if you're specifically denied access to anything on that table

Comment: I restarted the program and it suddenly shows all the columns. I must've pressed something to get rid of it by accident.

Comment: Glad you found a resolution - the convention is to please post as an answer (and accept it) to make this issue as resolved.

Comment: So you want me to post what you wrote?

Comment: I don't think I actually helped in the end - just that it resolved itself with a restart of SSMS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. One of the reasons could be lack of permission to **VIEW DEFINITION** on the particular table.
2. Another could be that I had lost connection at some point while trying to run a large query.

Restarting the system seemed to fix the problem, along with making sure you're not denied access to anything on the table.