# ORACLE query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database

Tags: sql, oracle, database-permissions

I'm looking for a query listing all the users that have access to a specific database. Hopefully similar to this one but to query Oracle database.
[SQL Server query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database)

Answer (score 2):

To query which user has been granted for a `system privilege` such as `DEBUG ANY PROCEDURE`, `ON COMMIT REFRESH`, `INSERT ANY TABLE`, `CREATE ANY JOB`, `FLASHBACK ANY TABLE` ... etc.

```
select p.* from dba_sys_privs p where p.grantee = upper('<your_user_name>');
```

To query `DML`, `EXECUTION`, `DEBUG` privileges on an object such as `TABLE`, `VIEW`, `PROCEDURE`, `FUNCTION` ... etc.

```
select p.* from dba_tab_privs p where p.grantee = upper('<your_user_name>');
```

To see which user granted the object privileges

```
select p.* from dba_tab_privs p where p.owner = upper('<your_user_name>');
```

may be used.

Comment: i'd like to have a single query.

Comment: @wendy - then join these together

Answer (score 1):

A database administrator (DBA) for Oracle can simply execute a query to view the rows in `DBA_SYS_PRIVS`, `DBA_TAB_PRIVS`, and `DBA_ROLE_PRIVS` to retrieve information about user privileges related to the **system**, **tables**, and **roles**, respectively.

For example, a DBA wishing to view all **system** privileges granted to all users would issue the following query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DBA_SYS_PRIVS;
```

To determine which users have *direct* grant access to a **table** we’ll use the `DBA_TAB_PRIVS` view:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DBA_TAB_PRIVS;
```

Finally, querying the `DBA_ROLE_PRIVS` view has much of the same information but applicable to **roles** instead, where the `GRANTED_ROLE` column specifies the role in question:

```
SELECT *
  FROM DBA_ROLE_PRIVS;
```

See the entire tutorial [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/oracle-user-privileges--how-to-show-all-privileges-for-a-user/).

Comment: I'd like to have a single query.

Comment: This view lists all grants for a particular user: select * from DBA_TAB_PRIVS where grantee = 'your user';