# Keeping User SQL Server Perms in Sync

Tags: sql-server, permissions

We have numerous dbs and logins. Gets difficult to keep everything in sync between Dev, Stage, Prod. Anyone know program or query to compare DBs on different environments and their users .

Difficulties:

Dev_User1 on Dev

Prod_User1 on Stage/Prod . User perms have to match so it has to be intelligent matches.

Answer (score 0):

You mean Microsoft SQL server? As it is not clear from tags.

We use DBComparer to compare databases, but I'm not aware of intelligent matches you are looking for.

Perhaps you can use SQL to list all permissions so you can compare it using a compare tool.
See [SQL Server query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database)