# SQL Server GRANT SELECT permissions Not Working

Tags: sql-server

I'm having an issue giving a single user the ability to perform

```
select * from msdb..sysmail_profile
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 1
> The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysmail_profile', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'

I've tried to grant permissions by using:

```
use msdb; 

grant select on msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile to [My User];
```

but still no avail. However, if I do the exact same grant permission command for `[Public]`, then the user is able to perform the needed select statement, but I don't want `[Public]` to have access to select from that table.

I have not found any Deny's anywhere for this user, yet I am still unable to give this single user `SELECT` permissions. Any thoughts?

Comment: When you say you haven't found any Deny permissions - where have you looked? Presumably you've checked `sys.database_permissions`

Comment: Correct, I ran a script that I had found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database  I am able to see that the User has Permission Type SELECT with PermissionState GRANT for ObjectName sysmail_profile.

Comment: FWIW, `dbo.sysmail_profile` is an undocumented system table. Try granting execute on `sysmail_help_profile_sp` to retrieve mail profile info.

Comment: Ok, I know I'll regret asking, but why does a user need to view sysmail_profile ?

Comment: This is within my test environment, to have a user to take the responsibility of dbmail. I am still relatively new with SQL and trying to get a better understanding of how permissions work down to a granular level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your context is not switched. Try with EXECUTE AS and see if the issue still persists. For me, the below code worked successfully without issues.

```sql
use master
go
CREATE LOGIN TestLogin with password = 'YOURSTRONGPASSWORD'
GO
use msdb
go
CREATE USER TestLogin for login testlogin
GO
grant select on msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile to [testlogin]
GO

EXECUTE AS user = 'Testlogin'
go
SELECT * FROM msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile
go
Revert
go
```

Comment: This seemed to work, not entirely sure what I was doing wrong, as I had granted permission to the table the same way, or so I thought.

Answer (score 0):

make sure in security > logins > [myuser]> user mapping > check msdb

(if the user still does not have access try to revoke public server role because I think the default in public server role for msdb is denied)

use msdb;
REVOKE select on msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile to public;