# Create DB audit specification without ALTER ANY DATABASE AUDIT

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, audit

SQL Server doc, topic [Create Database Audit Specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification?view=sql-server-2017), on Sub-topic Permissions, says:

> Users who have the ALTER ANY DATABASE AUDIT permission can create database audit specifications and bind them to any audit.

The user I am working on auditing the non-system db-s does not have the ALTER ANY DATABASE AUDIT permission granted on any of the non-system db-s. But it has granted the CONTROL SERVER permission.

As for the doc, I should not be able to create and manage database audit specifications.
In fact I do.

Am I missing something, or the documentation is wrong on this issue?

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/permissions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver16#permissions-naming-conventions): `CONTROL` : Confers ownership-like capabilities on the grantee. The grantee effectively has all defined permissions on the securable. A principal that has been granted CONTROL can also grant permissions on the securable. Because the SQL Server security model is hierarchical, CONTROL at a particular scope implicitly includes CONTROL on all the securables under that scope. For example, CONTROL on a database implies all .....

Comment: .... permissions on the database, all permissions on all assemblies in the database, all permissions on all schemas in the database, and all permissions on objects within all schemas within the database.

Comment: This could help: [SQL Server query to find all permissions/access for all users in a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048839/sql-server-query-to-find-all-permissions-access-for-all-users-in-a-database)

Comment: Essentially if you have `CONTROL` on something you can do whatever you want to it and anything under its control. So such a user would be able to whatever they want with the server and its databases. This is basically `sa` permissions right there.

Comment: As the job can be done, sure the privilege must be there.

But under topic "Crate Server Audit Specification", sub-topic Permission, same doc says:

"To create, alter, or drop a server audit, principals require the ALTER ANY SERVER AUDIT or the CONTROL SERVER permission."

Here we have a explicit mentioning of the "CONTROL SERVER" permission (as it works and it should be).

I thing it should have been the same under DB Audit specifications.

Comment: @altink - I've got great news for you! If you think the documentation should be changed, you can open up a PR. At the top of the page is a [link to edit](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/blob/live/docs/relational-databases/security/auditing/create-a-server-audit-and-database-audit-specification.md); I've provided it here for convenience. *I* don't think what you're proposing is a particularly good idea (i.e. to have to go through the docs and explicitly call out any implied permissions seems daunting and error prone), but my opinion doesn't matter; that of the maintainers *does*.

Comment: The documentation is never fully clear on permissions when there is a hierarchy involved. It often only tells you the *minimum* required permissions, but `CONTROL` is the highest level.

Comment: @BenThul perhaps he should add A PR removing reference to `CONTROL` in the "Server Audit Spec" :D

Comment: @Charlieface - your view on the matter matches mine. Great minds _et cetera_.